# What words are commonly mispronounced by literate people who read them before they heard them?

Tags: pronunciation, vocabulary, literature, list-request

Quite a few words are mispronounced by under-educated people, or people learning English as a second language. Some words are often mispronounced by quite educated people who read, and began reading high-level literature before they heard the vocabulary spoken.

This can lead to a vocabulary dissonance, occasionally leading to the belief that there are two words (the known spelling of one, and the verbal hearing of the same) where only one exists. Epitome is a common example that springs to mind.

Answer with a word and its proper pronunciation (and potentially, the commonly mistaken punctuation).

Comment: Can we have sources for all answers. Cuz this is SERRIIOOUUSSS business we are dealing with there

Comment: @Midhat ~ You mean like `SRS BSNS`

Comment: Pretty much every third word in any Harry Potter book.

Comment: As pronunciations vary between British English and American "English", which should the answers reflect?

Comment: @Orbling: Where the pronunciations differ, the difference should be noted.

Comment: This list is so full of awesome I can't even stand it.  I'm having an EPY-fone!

Comment: I mispronounced "totalitarianism", thinking that it is stressed at the first syllable, because there is the word "total". In reality, the second syllable is stressed.

Answer (score 100):

> **hyperbole** /haɪˈpɜrbəli/

(Evidently it's not the next step after the Super Bowl.)

Comment: +1 for superbowl, but what are the two ways to pronounce this?

Comment: Hy-per-bo-lee (or near enough)

Comment: The mispronunciation is HY-per-BOWL, and the correct pronunciation is hy-PER-bo-LEE.

Comment: OK, it's a greek word (ὑπερβολή) so its pronounciation is close to the greek pronounciation; what I find funny is, me being Greek but never having heard the english word spoken out loud, I also thought it rhymed with “superbowl” :)

Comment: I'm going to start calling it the Su-PER-bol-EE

Comment: I've never heard it pronounced other than "HYperbowl". Is hy-PER-bo-LEE some sort of attempt at French sophistication, à la Hyperbolé ? (with an acute final e)

Comment: Actually, I think it's a Greek word. And then I realized I'm on the internet, so, yes, it is Greek, says Wikipedia. :)

Comment: @smirkingman -- Seriously?

Comment: @smirkingman : you are mistaken. French mathematicians and rhetors pronounce it approximately eepairbol.

Answer (score 75):

I had quite a few of these growing up.  The one I think is most common is **segue**.  Did you know it's pronounced "segway"?  I didn't for a very *very* long time.

Comment: Actually, I think I got that one straight before I ever tried to use it myself, but I did say "tongoo" instead of "tongue."...For the record though, I was, like, six. :)

Comment: "Segway" isn't quite the correct pronunciation (`seg - WEH` is closer), but it's definitely better than `seg - goo`.

Comment: I always thought it was "seeg" or "seyg" in the same way "The Hague" is pronounced "hayg".

Comment: I didn't, until now. In fact, I read your answer as _.. most common is_ ___seeg___

Comment: @Noldorin: I used to think it was `seg-yoo`, like "argue", "continue", etc. Don't ask me what I thought about "fugue".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Haha, fair enough. If you aren't familiar with French, it's an easy enough mistake to make.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: "The Hague" is a name of Flemish (Dutch) origin, not French. Different rules apply.

Comment: @Noldorin, I couldn't see how segue could be French (would it be written següé?) so I checked — it's apparently Italian.

Comment: @Neil: It's quite plausible for it to have been originally French and undergone changes in phonology. In this case, it's Latin by way of Italian.

Comment: @Noldorin: I think it’s pretty fair to say that in English the pronunciation of *segue* is \seg-way\.  The general rule is that borrowed words get their closest approximation *within the native phonetic stock*; and word final \-eh\ is fairly foreign to English, so approximating it to \-ay\ seems quite reasonable (compare English pronunciations of *café*, *forte*, *cum laude*, which all have slightly different vowels in the original but become \-ay\ in English).

Comment: Segway (the walking thing people stand on) and segue are homophones, aren't they?

Comment: Am I the only person who pronounces it as /si:g/ (like "seeg")? Being ostensibly bilingual in English but never speaking a word of English for years (regardless of reading most of my books in English and being English online) may have taken its toll...

Answer (score 68):

> colonel /ˈkərnl/

This has to be the worst word for me - I know that is pronounced ker-nil, but EVERY time I read it the pronunication in my head is col-o-nel. How is *colonel* "ker-nil" anyway?! :)

Comment: Was bothering me so I found out why: http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/752/why-is-colonel-pronounced-kernel

Comment: I think we should give up the joke and go back to spelling it "coronel". :P

Comment: I knew I was at the point of dropping off in one of my maths lectures when I started writing about the colonel of a function.

Comment: For reasons best known to my psychologist, when reading, I often read it col-o-nel, but in the voice of German officer from a B&W war film. In fact, my 'inner voice' articulates lots of words in some rather weird and wonderful ways. ;)

Comment: A colonel of truth? The Linux colonel?

Comment: @Stein, the Linux colonel is lower ranked than the MS-DOS General Failure.

Comment: Fun fact: in the TCG Net-Runner, there was a card named "Colonel Failure" - if I had known that colonel was actually pronounced "kernel" it would have be fun on two different ways!

Comment: The word 'colonel' has two pronunciations. American military says colonel /ˈkɜrnəl/ where as British army say /ˈkɜːnᵊl/

Comment: @Lohoris: Hmm, we can have a "General Failure" and we can have a "Major Failure". It stands to reason that something in the middle shoudl be a "Colonel Failure".

Comment: @Thorbjorn: I know the military is spying on me. I got a message "General Failure reading hard drive."

Answer (score 65):

**victuals**

I always thought it was VICK-chew-als, while it is actually VITT-les.

Comment: Another case of "colonelisation", where the orthography was changed from the original French loan (vittaylle) to reflect *its* origin in Latin (victualia) despite no change in pronunciation. Sigh.

Comment: Wait, those are the same word‽

Comment: More on victuals and other latinised French-loans:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34568/are-there-other-words-with-the-same-weird-spelling-pronunciation-combo-as-vict/34570#34570

Comment: Oh.  My.  God.  I feel dumb.

Comment: I always thought vittles was just Granny Clampet's way of saying it, and that "vick-tu-als" was the correct way. I very recently heard or saw some reference otherwise that I didn't take to be authoritative, but apparently it's correct.

Answer (score 61):

> **epitome** /ɪˈpɪtəmi/

Comment: An epi"tome" would be the tome-length epilogue at the end of a book.

Comment: This is really the epitome of these words. I had an epiphany when I realized my error.

Comment: Why do the English language insist on keeping the spelling of loanwords? If you mean "epittomy" can't you just write it that way? ;)

Comment: Incidentally, in Italian it is written exactly the same, but pronounced in a different way.

Comment: For years I thought this was EPPY-tome.

Comment: Shia Lebouf pronounces epitome (MP3): http://www.streetcarnage.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/epitome.mp3

Answer (score 46):

Uggh, as one of the over-literates you mentioned, I have a lot of these. However, I have no idea as to how common mine are or may have been.

**Facade** should be pronounced "fuh-SAHD" (/fəˈsɑːd/). At first, I pronounced it "fack-AID."

Comment: +1 funny.  I'm going to say FACK-AID from now on, especially when talking to the DESIGN PATTERN evangelists.

Comment: French: façade.

Comment: is that an ant-eye-pattern?

Comment: @Taldaugion: And what's wrong if it is?

Comment: This is why English words should keep the accents (and cedilla in this case) of foreign words.

Comment: @Noldorin: That really wouldn't help, IMO. I'd seen a cedilla on the place-name "Caracau" and I still thought that was "Carah-cow." Accents don't help unless you know what they mean....kind of like the whole "ueber-" thing a while ago. If you aren't familiar with German, you won't know what the umlaut means. If you haven't heard "facade" before, you won't know how to pronounce it if you read it. Sometimes "c"s sound like "s" in English. Facade is just one of those words to most people, and you learn it by hearing it. Same way you learn "face" or "incise."

Comment: Fair enough. I say this only because I know enough French, but I can't really speak for those that don't know French...

Comment: This is one of those words where I'd keep the cedilla while writing in English.

Comment: This is even worse than keeping foreign spelling, keeping it but changing it slightly. A slightly better spelling would be "fasade" which is incidentally how we write it in Norwegian, but still it has a pronounciation that is not possible to write in English. (But "face aid" is at least better than "f*ck head")

Comment: As a native french speaker, many of these words trip me because my fellow American english speakers get all tripped up when I pronounce french words the french way. I pronounce facade the american way: fuh-sad, no fass-ad, like I would in french.

Comment: For a long time I knew the spoken word "fuh-SAHD" (/fəˈsɑːd/) and the written word _facade_ (which I vaguely thought of as being pronounced fuh-kaid'), but hadn't connected the two synonyms.

Comment: The misspelling **facade* (pronounced /fəˈkeɪd/, or approximately “fuck-AID”) is catecrestic for *façade* (pronounced  /fəˈsɑːd/), and can be used to humorous effect; it should probably be respelled as *fassade* or something.  Similarly, **naive* (pronounced /neɪv/ to rhyme with its only English lookalike, *waive*) is catecrestic for *naïve* (pronounced /nɑˈiːv/), which should really be respelled as *nayeve* or something.

Answer (score 45):

Greenwich is "grenitch", not "green-witch".

Comment: Well, there's a million British placenames that are traps for the unwary.  Leicester is another famous one, but I remember there was once a dance troupe called "The Cholmondeleys and the Featherstonehaughs" (pronounced, The Chumleys and the Fanshaws")!

Comment: worcestershire is another good one

Comment: Loughborough is another. (luff-bra)

Comment: Good lord people.  How in the heck do you go from Featherstonehaughs to Fanshaw?!?!

Comment: Warwickshire for another. Not to mention all the odd abbreviations. Salop, anyone?

Comment: @morganpdx - it's deliberate. It lets people know if you are really in 'our set' or if you just read the name.

Comment: Greenwich is "grenitch", eh? Makes me hungry for a sammich ...

Answer (score 44):

> Awry   /əˈraɪ/

Wrong: AWE-ree

Right: uh-RY

> Omnipotent   /ɒmˈnɪpət(ə)nt/

Wrong: Omni-Potent

Right: omNIPPOtent (think "hippo")

Comment: I still do this...

Comment: common English pattern: stress goes on the antepenultimate syllable

Comment: Omnipotent comes from omni (all) and potent (from posse in latin). I understand people who say omni-potent. There's no etymologic reason to say om-nippo-tent :s

Comment: Nippo sounds like sushi.

Comment: good one on Awry - I still do awe-ree

Comment: Damn.  I had had absolutely no idea.

Comment: On RHS of pond, always AWE-ree

Comment: And enterprises of great pith and moment, // 
With this regard, their currents turn awry, //
And lose the name of action. //

Comment: @Elenaher Your etymological reason hold no water. Stress regression is very well-documented in English.

Answer (score 43):

I have a hard time avoiding pronouncing the word 'gaol' with a hard 'g', when it's really a homophone for 'jail'.

Comment: Wait, so it's not pronounced "gowl"...? Whoopsie. Not only do I have a lot of these, I also apparently haven't discovered some of them yet...This is educational AND saving me from some possible future embarrassment. Awesome.

Comment: Anyone who reads Dickens in high school would come across this word. I always thought, "gosh, I'm glad we don't have gaols in America, they sound horrible."

Comment: Fr.: geôle; like most words related to justice, a legacy of William the Conqueror.

Comment: In the same vein: “gaoler”. But since nobody uses these spellings any more …

Comment: @Konrad, the Guardian still did, last time I read a copy. But they are uncommon.

Comment: @Brian: Most amusing: [site:guardian.co.uk +gaoler](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:guardian.co.uk+%2Bgaoler) vs. [site:guardian.co.uk +jailer](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:guardian.co.uk+%2Bjailer)

Comment: @Konrad, it does say in their style book "jail, not gaol" (http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/j).

Comment: I'm reminded of a British immigrant to the U.S. who ran for some minor office. His opponent was currently the county sheriff. In a debate the sheriff made a big point about "goals", saying we need clear goals, etc. So the Briton replied, "His experience is gaols, not goals!" The quip fell rather flat to Americans, who pictured it as "jails, not goals".

Answer (score 42):

> Ennui /ɑ̃nɥi/, /ɒnˈwiː/

Imagine my surprise at learning that it's pronounced "on-wi" and not "eh-new-ee"!!

Comment: Oh...I can imagine it really, really well.

Comment: You mean it's *not* pronounced eh-new-ee?

Comment: From Old French enui (annoyance, apathy).

Comment: Isn't it "on-wee"?

Comment: I originally thought it was "in-you-eye".

Comment: I used to pronounce this as "en-wah" `:P`

Comment: @MGOwen: this is the [father-bother merge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_low_back_vowels#Father-bother_merger).  For many US speakers, “ahn” and “on” represent the same vowel.  For me (and presumably you) they’re completely different — so “ahn-wi” is accurate for them, though incorrect for us.  Editing it to “on”, though, since that’s I believe accurate for everybody…

Comment: Just for the perverse: try to pronounce ennuyeux (approximative sense: boring, vexing).

Answer (score 40):

Draught.

as in draught beer - pronounced as draft and not dr-aw-ght

Comment: But you spell through T-H-R-U, and I'm with you on that;
cos we spell it "thruff".  -- Eddie Izzard

Comment: @Stein G. Strindhaug:  Reminds me of Bernard Shaw's *ghoti* pronounced *fish* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti

Comment: Well, trough is just as bad.

Comment: @Stein And we say "herb", because there's a f***ing 'h' there..

Comment: mind = blown ... I feel a bit embarrassed now.

Comment: I just had to replace draught in my head at the grocery store this morning as I walked by a stack of Guinness. "Drawt Guinness?  Oh right draft."

Comment: @JoseK: *ghoti* was invented, but try the nation *Kiribati* (pronounced ˈkɪrɨbæs, an attempt at "Gilberts") and its island *Kiritimati* (pronounced kəˈrɪsməs, an attempt at "Christmas")

Comment: Which, of course, should not be confused with *drought* (dr-OWT - a long dry spell), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drought

Comment: There is a Dr. Seuss collection called "The Tough Coughs As He Ploughs the Dough".

Comment: .... 25 years old, and linguistics as a hobby.... and I just NOW learn this. I thought they were different words! I don't drink beer, so explains why I never learned to begin with...

Comment: @Aequit: were you researching for the answer on drafting while cycling?

Answer (score 36):

The one that always gets me is **quay**.

I still tend to pronounce it "kway", even though I know the correct pronunciation is "key".

Comment: I've heard a professional voice actor pronounce it "kway". In fact, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quay) gives both pronunciations plus a third, "kay".

Comment: I've never understood why it's "key".  Isn't this word from French? In my French we'd say "kay".

Comment: Professional voice actors make plenty of mistakes. I have a couple of science audiobooks with some shocking mispronunciations.

Comment: I'm going to have to use this one in a sentence a few times to make it sink in. Good one.

Answer (score 35):

Late addition, but one I've just learned of: **viscount**. Apparently it's pronounced **VYE-count**. Who knew?

Comment: Everyone who likes chocolate biscuits...

Comment: There goes my great joke about the viscount's discount.

Comment: French again. To be pronounced like 'vicomte'.

Comment: Actually, it’s /ˈvaɪkaʊnt/.

Answer (score 32):

Worcestershire, as in the sauce. The obvious pronunciation is "wor-chest-er-shy-er", but apparently the correct pronunciation is "werst-er-sher".

Comment: Ditto Leicestershire (obvious: lie-CES-ter-SHI-er, correct: LES-ter-sher), Warwick (obvious: WAR-wick, correct: WAR-rick).

Comment: Place names; there's a well with no bottom. Consider also Alnwick (an-ick, but don't forget Alnmouth is al-un-mouth), Bosham (bozzum) but Cosham (cosh-um), Marylebone (mar-le-bun) and Holborn (ho-bun). And that's not counting exotica like Woolfardisworthy (woolsery) and Kirkudbright (kik-oo-bry).

Comment: Also: Towcester (toaster), Bicester (bister), Frome (froom), Keynsham (kayn-shum).

Comment: Cindi is right. In Worcestershire - most of the r's are silent, so this should be WIST-ih-sure

Comment: Yes, usually the "ces" in English towns/cities is omitted from pronunciation. @cindi is right, we (I'm from Worcestershire!) usually omit the r sound. Another curveball: *Leominster* (correct: lemm-ster).

Comment: And then there are Scottish placenames: Milngavie is "miln-guy".  I think a lot of them are regular in Gaelic.

Comment: **“werst-er-sher”?** I believe that’s wrong. It’s /ˈwʊstərˌʃɪər/ or /ˈwʊstərˌʃər/ (the first vowel is like the one in *foot*).

Comment: When visiting London last summer, I was surprised to learn Tottenham is actually pronounced with *two* syllables, something like Tott'num.

Comment: @Brian - yes, you could do on forever: Bicester/bister, Barrow-in-Furness/Barrow-in-Furnace, Edinburgh/Edinburuh, etc...

Comment: @cindi Alas poor worick. I knew him, Horatio.

Comment: @CJM: I would have said "Edinbruh" for Edinburgh.

Comment: These are called syncopated words.

Comment: @Steve - We all commonly say 'Edinbruh' but AFAIK an articulate Scot would have an extra syllable: http://inogolo.com/pronunciation/Edinburgh

Comment: And Launceston in Cornwall is pronounced LAHN-s@n while Launceston in Tasmania is pronounced LAWN-cess-t@n.

Comment: I remember being told once that it's supposed to sound like "what's this here" mumbled and slurred together. Such as if a confused person looked at the sauce, pointed to it, and said "what's this here sauce?"

Comment: Pass the _werscherstershire_ sauce please. And I had to unnecessarily suffer all that tongue twisting.

Comment: Within the UK city of Milton Keynes, there are three areas named Loughton, Woughton and Broughton. They are pronounced Lau-ton (first syllable rhymes with "cow"), Woof-ton and Braw-ton (like "brought")...

Comment: @jjackson hahahah! We do that in the states too, although it's surely inherited from England: Worcester, MA pronounced 'WUS-tah', and not "WAR-chest-er" like I thought as a kid.

Comment: "Worcestershire sauce" is pronounced "Wooster sauce".  There's a Kipling quote about a foreigner whose English was perfect "except that he would keep asking for the Worcestershire sauce".

Comment: @PSM: That is superb.

Comment: @TimLymington The OED givs  /ˈwʊstəʃər/, but I agree with you.

Answer (score 31):

*Biopic*, which does **not** rhyme with *myopic* (stress on "o").  It's pronounced like *bio-pic* (primary stress on "bi").  Even after I found that out, I still don't like it.

Comment: I did not know that until just now. Good one.

Comment: …because it is short for *bio(graphical) (motion) pic(ture)*

Comment: I still don't like it! :)

Comment: Er, doesn't myopic rhyme with bio-pic? (I see there are two pronunciations for "myopic", with different vowels for the 'o', but doesn't one of them rhyme with bio-pic?)

Comment: *Myopic* has stress on the second syllable, while *biopic* has primary stress on the first syllable and secondary stress on the final syllable.

Comment: I didn't know the difference for many decades.

Comment: Apparently, I've been pronouncing "myopic" wrong. :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Thanks, stress is one of the harder areas of English pronunciation, which most Indian speakers never consider... Even after listening to the words, my natural tendency is to discard the stresses as unnecessary and pronounce them with equal stress so they seem to rhyme. :-)

Comment: Woah. Good one. Never heard anyone say it this way and I think it would sound forced.

Answer (score 30):

[Yosemite](http://www.nps.gov/yose/), as in the national park in California.

For the longest time I thought it was pronounced "Yo-sem-ite" instead of "Yo-sem-i-tee"

Cartoons failed me, I never made the connection to "Yosemite Sam" from the Bugs Bunny Show.

Comment: Yosemite, to rhyme with Vegemite.

Comment: @Sam: Really?  When I told people how I lost my Vegemite a while back, I thought I must have mispronounced it, cause I got some weird looks.

Comment: I annoy campers who frequent that park by calling it YOSE-MIGHT

Answer (score 29):

Linux.

Many people pronounce it "LYE-nucks" (I do) but, as it's based on the Swedish name Linus (Linus Torvalds is Finnish but speaks Swedish).  Thus the pronunciation should be "Leenux" or "Lihn-ucks" (/ˈlɪnəks/).

Comment: Around here I more frequently hear "LEN-icks"

Comment: That is also true for many Linux distribution as well. Some people say oo-bun-too, while others say oo-boon-too, gen-too, jen-too, soo-seh, soos, etc. BTW, I used to say leenux, then heard a lot of lie-nux, so thought I was wrong, but never like lie-nux, so I still look around when I say "I use leenux" to check whether someone will correct me.

Comment: As a reference, here's the classic [linux.au](http://www.ep.ph.bham.ac.uk/poynters/mirror/linux.au) clip: "I'm Linus Torvalds and I pronounce Linux as /ˈlɪnəks/."

Comment: Oh, and check out [this](http://inogolo.com/pronunciation/d1083/Linus_Torvalds) too; a nice Youtube clip with Linus saying both his name and Linux.

Comment: Same goes for Ubuntu, which *should* be pronounced /Oo'boontoo/.

Comment: Just in case anyone else has trouble with .au files, here is a link to the mp3: http://www.paul.sladen.org/pronunciation/torvalds-says-linux.mp3

Answer (score 28):

**Hiccough**

Apparently this is not pronounced to rhyme with cough, but in exactly the same way as "hiccup".  Which fooled me for many years, for obvious reasons!

Comment: I love archaic spellings. Lets bring them back. :-)           Plough, for example.

Comment: Don't forget Draught.

Comment: @Carole-Lynn It’s not an archaic spelling; it’s an erroneous one.

Answer (score 25):

Here's one I only recently learned I was saying wrong all my life.

The name of children's book author Dr. Seuss

It does NOT rhyme with Goose. It is pronounced like Soyce.

```
You’re wrong as the deuce  
And you shouldn’t rejoice  
If you’re calling him Seuss  
He pronounces it Soice  
     -Alexander Liang  (Colleague of Geisel)
```

Comment: Uh, where'd you hear this? I've certainly only heard it pronounced to rhyme with "goose", and I daresay that's how Mr. Geisel pronounced it, too. (The fact that the digraph "eu" is pronounced "oy" in German is largely irrelevant.)

Comment: Actually, he's right...sort of. The man's name _should_ be pronounced "soyce," and that _is_ how Seuss pronounced it. However, he adopted the "soos" pronunciation since he thought it was advantageous for a children's author's name to rhyme with Mother Goose and most people pronounced it that way anyway. I'm stealing all of this from Wikipedia btw...

Comment: http://libraries.ucsd.edu/about/geisel-building.html.    "The University Library Building was renamed Geisel Library in honor of Audrey and Theodor Geisel (Dr. Seuss) for the generous contributions they have made to the library and their devotion to improving literacy."  Interesting reasoning @kitukwfer, when I'm out visiting in the area, his name is pronounced "soos" by academics and guides.

Answer (score 22):

**lieutenant**

This is a word that is pronounced logically by Americans, but in Britain we pronounce it as "lef-tenant" which is not at all obvious.

Comment: This really sums up why English is so hard to learn!

Comment: Ah, I was going to add this one if someone hadn't already. Australia follows the weird British pronunciation for this one.

Comment: Because that's how it was originally pronounced in Norman French, with an 'f'. Modern French changed and the english spelling followed it - while of course keeping the old pronounciation

Comment: Don't even get me started on Colonel.

Answer (score 17):

'Read', as in

> John is dry (read: boring).

I believe there's a fair amount of agreement that the correct pronunciation is /rid/ ("reed").

Comment: This one is great because so many people are convinced that they knew the right one all along, even when they are wrong.  Crazy ask.metafilter thread from yesterday: http://ask.metafilter.com/162666/Is-the-parenthetical-read-pronounced-reed-or-red

Comment: Annnd [a nearly identical thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/92739/How-do-you-pronounce-read) from two years ago, heh.  Good times!

Comment: If only more people learned foreign languages, there wouldn't be so much confusion. There are identical constructions in many languages where the verb form is not a homograph and clearly imperative ("lees" in Dutch, "lies" or "sprich" in German, "читай" in Russian, to name but a few).

Comment: I would pronounce _read_ in the same way I would pronounce _eat_; I am sure I wrongly pronounce another word containing _ea_, though. `:-)`

Comment: strange, I always thought it was pronounced "red". As in, "that last word that was just there, that should have been read 'boring'"

Comment: Is this a case of mispronunciation or choosing the wrong word? Read ("reed") and read ("red") are not the same; if you "mispronounce" read in this sentence you get a different sentence with a different meaning.

Comment: Definitely sounds like "reed".   It's an instruction to the reader.  "read the previous statement as meaning ____".

Comment: Both pronunciations make sense, and have the same ultimate outcome.

Comment: The English town Reading is pronounced like the Californian town Redding.

Answer (score 15):

**Misled**

When I was a kid I thought it was pronounced like a strange combination of "miser" and "tiled". You know, mise-uld!

Comment: Or rhyming with "bristled".

Comment: +1, because when I was young I genuinely thought there was a verb "to misle", which rhymed with "lies'll".

Comment: I'm with mmyers - I was totally mistled by this when I was young.

Comment: My husband recounts that for the longest time, he thought it was myzled, past tense of myzle...

Comment: Isn’t that what happens when you get an ICBM landed on you? :)

Answer (score 14):

Names are tricky too.

- Freud is pronounced froid, when it looks like frude.
- Wagner is vagner which is different in English names pronounced whagner.
- Euler looks like u-ler rather than oiler.
- Job in the Bible is Johb, not job like work.
- Sade the singer sounds like sha-day.
- Eritrea looks like e-REE-tria rather than er-re-TREE-a.
- All of the Spanish names and French-spelled native names in America.
- Versailles, Kentucky is pronounced ver-sales rather than ver-sigh.

As a teacher I have heard "infrared" pronounced in-frared rather than infra-red. I heard "stomach ache" pronounced "stomatch atch" by non-native speakers rather than stomik ake.

Comment: English speakers tend to mispronounce the philosopher Immanuel Kant even if they do know the correct pronunciation of his second name.

Comment: In German, the 'eu' letter pair is pronounced 'oy', as in the English word 'boy'.  That's why 'Freud' and 'Euler' are pronounced the way they are.

Comment: Job/Johb seems to have regional variations.  Every church I've been in in the west of Scotland pronounces it Job, whereas now living in the east everyone pronounces it Johb.

Comment: Illinois boasts Des Plaines, pronounced Dez Planes and Marseilles, pronounced Mar-sails; also Cairo, pronounced Kay-row.

Comment: In Versailles, Kentucky, they call it "nuke-ye-lar".

Comment: The first three are German names.  -1, this is not a post about "English" words, but rather the fact that languages who share alphabet use different sounds.  (The "w" in german sounds more like our English "v" which is why Wagner is "vagner") To pay respect to those people, we try to pronounce the name as would be done in the original language.

Answer (score 13):

**sepulcher**   /ˈsɛpəlkər/

Correct pronunciation is "seh-pul-ker." I first said "seh-puhl-chur."

Comment: The British spelling of this word, *sepulchre*, hints more at the correct pronunciation, and is closer to the French in which the `ch` is also hard.

Comment: ...I just realized that I pronounce this with a German ch sound instead of a k. I guess when in doubt I just go with something that sounds in-between...?

Comment: At http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Sepulcher you can see that the en-US is "seh-pul-ker" and en-UK is "seh-puhl-cher"

Answer (score 13):

**Boolean**   /ˈbuːlɪən/

- Wrong: boo-LEEN
- Right: BOO-lee-en

Comment: This is easy to remember when you realise that it's named after George Boole. So it's Boolean as in Herculean.

Comment: I used to say "boolian" `:P`

Comment: @Kit: If your "-lian" suffix sounds the same as it would in the words "mammalian", or "Mongolian", then I think you were pronouncing it correctly. Herculean is pronounced hur-kyuh-lee-uhn or hur-kyoo-lee-uhn, so Boolean is pronounced BOO-lee-uhn

Comment: Herculean is pronounced hur-kyuh-LEE-uhn, so it follows that boolean should be pronounced boo-LEE-uhn.

Comment: What’s sad about this one is that we abbreviate Boolean as “bool” instead of “boole”.

Answer (score 13):

Ironically, I find that **pronunciation** is frequently mispronounced.

Comment: Not to mention, frequently misspelled, lol.

Comment: @jyc23 Or misspoken.  My (Dutch) girlfriend frequently says this as, "pronounucation," which nearly always earns a raised eyebrow.

Answer (score 11):

Behemoth. (OED:   /bɪˈhiːməθ/,  /-ɔːθ/)

I always stress the first syllable (BEE-heh-moth), even after hearing it with the stress on the second syllable (buh-HEE-muth). I just can't get seem to get past it.

Comment: The correct pronunciation is BEH-heh-moth as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: This is a Hebrew word, and in Hebrew, the last syllable is accented, therefore b'heh-MOTH. Yet, many Henrew words are pronounced differently in English.

Comment: Indeed, a Hebrew word for a large mythological beast. Interestingly its plural form denotes _great_ and not _many_. Elohim (God) is another example.

Comment: By the way, the word is pronounced _beh-heh-MOT_.

Comment: I've ended up pronouncing it more like beer-moth. Which is useful if the behemoth that confronts you is a moth that likes beer.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Maybe in Hebrew, but not in English - dictionaries list [various pronunciations](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/behemoth), but the "th" is invariably a soft "th" not a "t".

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Behemoth gives buh-HEE-muth for en-US and beh-heh-MOT for en-UK

Comment: @wil, it is the hebrew pronunciation that drifted away. It used to be pronounced with the 'th' sound at the end by the hebrew speakers, until quite recently when Hebrew lost this sound completely.

Answer (score 11):

I have this problem with character names in novels. Example, Hermione I pronounced as "her-mee-own", Egwene from Wheel of Time as "Egg-ween", etc. I realize I just gloss over the names really and don't even fully pronounce them in my head anyway.

About actual words... I generally have disagreements with people. Like I'll think "niche" should be pronounced "neesh", not "nitch," and "clique" as "cleek," not "click."

Comment: I say "neesh" too! :)

Comment: I say both neesh and cleek too - perhaps I've learned too much French?

Comment: I once lost a spelling bee on "clique", because the teacher told me to spell "click". I still think it was unfair.

Comment: +1 for "neesh". I hate "nitch". Grrrr, it makes me angry.

Comment: Niche and clique are both correct in British English.

Comment: With made-up words and names it's basically impossible to determine the author's intent unless they stick to the most basic spelling rules.  In Wheel of Time, Mazrim Taim's last name does not rhyme with "tame", it's "tah-EEM". Thanks Robert Jordan! That's totally obvious.  Oh, I should have read the glossary first, you say? No.

Comment: ha ha - "I just gloss over the names really and don't even fully pronounce them in my head anyway" - i do that too, in novels. In my head I just look at the shape of the letters and think "them".

Comment: I am so with you on niche and clique. Hate 'nitch' and 'click'. The other way of pronounciation is more elegant-sounding.

Comment: I think many corrected their pronunciation of 'Hermione' after the Harry Potter movies came out.

Answer (score 11):

**Queue** /kjuː/

I've never known how to pronounce this. On the rare occasions when it comes up in conversation, I generally say "Qu... K... Line."

Comment: FYI: "Queue" is a homophone with "cue". I believe "queue" is vastly more common than "line" in British English.

Comment: We British do love a good queue.

Comment: It's pronounced /kwewe/ of course, just like "through" is pronounced /throff/.... (I'm joking of course)

Comment: @Stein: It's pronounced kyuyuyuyuyu (depending how long).

Comment: I pronounce and spell it in software as "Q".  So I have "MyQ" and YourQ and ThisQ variables in the code. (with descriptive names)

Answer (score 10):

I'm really going to embarrass myself, but I was in high school before I realized the word I had been reading, "subtle," was the same as the word I had been speaking: suht-l. In my mind SUBTLE and "SUDDLE" were two words that meant the same thing!

Comment: There's a suddle difference.

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled upon this thread today and I am so pleased that someone resurrected it just a few hours ago.

I grew up in a small town in the deep South, which didn't create a lot of opportunity to hear the words I was reading in spoken form.  I was in my twenties before I learned that hors d'oeuvres (ôr dûrvz) was NOT pronounced (whores duh vree).

Recently, I discovered that my own teenager was having similar difficulty with a word that she had seen written but never heard aloud.  This discovery was made when she jokingly called me a twat (pronounced to rhyme with brat), lol! Not only did I corrected her pronunciation (twot), but also told her the meaning of the word since she had no idea.  Her response?  "Oh my gosh!!  Why are people calling each other THAT??"

Comment: Hahaha. I forgot about "hors d'oeuvres." I pronounced them "horse doovers."

Comment: Umm... [twat](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/twat_1) *does* rhyme with [brat](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/brat) where I come from!

Comment: Where I come from both pronunciations occur, and many who don't even know the anatomical referent use it as slang for 'idiot' (exactly as with *berk*). Some who would normally say *twat* for 'idiot' actually distinguish and use *twot* for the coarser meaning, but I've not come across the reverse.

Comment: I had to google quite a while to find out what Luda meant by whore-derves http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur4QfJrrj84 :-)

Answer (score 9):

Paradigm |**par**-*uh*-dahym| (OED:   Brit.  /ˈparədʌɪm/, U.S.  /ˈpɛrəˌdaɪm/)

I've winced a couple times when people have said |**par**-*uh*-**di**-jum|

Comment: Or Para-dig'em :)

Comment: "par-uh-dahym" seems a strange pronunciation to me. I say "pare-ah-dime".

Comment: Correct pronunciation is PAR-a-dim

Comment: And who exactly is the arbiter of "correct?"

Comment: Just use the paradigmatic pronunciation.

Comment: And what is the paradigmatic pronunciation of 'paradigmatic'?

Answer (score 9):

Askance. Not ASK-ance, but a-SKANCE. When you look askance at someone, you're giving them a sideways look, not a questioning one, as I used to think.

Answer (score 9):

**Rapport**   /ræˈpɔr/

Pronounced ra-PORE, not ra-PORT. French, but not obviously so.

Comment: That's just because the French never pronounce the end of any words.  Chateaux -> Chat-O.

Answer (score 9):

This question calls for a mention of [**The Chaos**](http://ncf.idallen.com/english.html) by Gerard Nolst Trenité:

> Dearest creature in creation
> Studying English pronunciation,
> I will teach you in my verse
> Sounds like corpse, corps, horse and worse.
>
> I will keep you, Susy, busy,
> Make your head with heat grow dizzy;
> Tear in eye, your dress you'll tear;
> Queer, fair seer, hear my prayer.
>
> […](http://ncf.idallen.com/english.html)

Comment: +1 for mentioning this, a great inventory of English stubbornness.

Answer (score 8):

Inventory. I (and no doubt many others who spent a significant amount of time playing text adventures), thought it was in-VENT-uh-ree, not IN-vuhn-tree.

Comment: I just listened to the pronunciation on Merriam-Webster and it definitely sounded more like the first one to me. I'm also pretty sure I've heard the first one on TV, not the second.

Comment: M-W clearly pronounces it IN-ven-tor-y, with secondary stress on tor.  Just like me.

Comment: I think this may be a UK/US thing, with the UK using the first pronunciation, and the US, the second.

Comment: I pronounced it like "infrantry" for a while.

Comment: Seems common to hear both "in-ven-tree" and "IN-ven-tory".   I like the latter since the former sounds too much like "infantry".

Comment: I've always heard en-vin-tor-ee here in east coast USA.

Answer (score 8):

Height sounds like high+t, which is logical I suppose, but I used to think it rhymed with eight. Like another poster, I got 'recipe' wrong too, rhyming it with 'ripe'. And when I told a native speaker about that, he said that 'recipe' followed a common pattern, like 'Hebrides' - that's how I learned that wasn't pronounced he-brides.

And how is a poor foreigner supposed to know whether 'ea' is pronounced 'ee' or as 'ea' in 'bear'? For example, if an activity wears you out (ea), you get weary (ee). Yeah, that makes sense(!)

Comment: Wait. "weary" has an "ee" sound? Apparently knowing what sound "ea" makes isn't something native speakers necessarily know either...

Comment: @kitukwfyer: Weary ("weer-ee") means tired. You were probably saying "Wary" (rhymes with "bear-y"), which means cautious.

Comment: @RodeoClown: Indeed. I'm well aware of the difference in meaning. I don't pronounce "wary" and "weary" identically, but it doesn't rhyme with...say "bleary" when I say it either...The vowel sounds more like a short i than anything else. Who knows why?

Comment: @bbleeker, I hear you. And to further confuse you, "ea" can also be prounced short "u" as in Earth and "ah" as in "hearth".

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing French words are at the top of the list.

Comment: Any foreign imports, really. I remember once someone pronouncing the German "nicht" as "nitch-tee." O.o

Comment: Yeah but French words are really messed up if you don't know French. I mean who would think that rendezvous is pronounced rondeyvoo.

Comment: That's true, I forgot about that "ren-dezz-vuss" incident, but I still don't pronounce any of the names in Troy correctly. I only pronounce latin words correctly because I took a couple years of latin. I had an English teacher who pronounced "Pompey" as "Pompeii"...Whatever. This is really a matter of perception/opinion, I suppose. :)

Comment: Part of the difficulty with French is that it appears in many cases as if a word could be a legitimate English word, but the rules of pronunciation differ. Forget. Mallet.

Comment: @mickeyf: I think it's the other way around... Lots of English words look like a legitimate French word. That's where many of the words came from, after all. French rules for pronunciation are, dare I say, more consistent than English

Comment: @Atomix - True enough, but the difficulties we're talking about are those suffered by the Anglophones...

Comment: Foyer. "foy-yay" sounds snobbish to me, so I stick with the American pronunciation, "foy-yer".

Answer (score 7):

**Moot**, as in *The point is moot.*  I often hear people say *The point is mute.*  Not only mispronounced, but misunderstood.

Comment: I actually think this is more from people using the wrong word than mispronouncing it.

Comment: Joey from Friends said the point is **moo**, it's a cow's opinion....

Comment: This is actually an [eggcorn](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/english/41/mute/)

Answer (score 7):

I too had several of these while growing up.  Two that spring to mind:

**Integer** — pronounced with a soft ‘g’, but I used a hard ‘g’.

**Elite** — rhymes with ‘delete’, but I would rhyme it with ‘delight’.

Comment: Integer is pronounced in-te-jer (hard g) and Integral is pronounced as in-teg-rul or in-te-grul depending on the context.

Comment: @John Gietzen: I meant soft g as in "George" and hard g as in "go". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_and_soft_G

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Answer (score 6):

Many mythological names. The one that stands out for me is [Terpsichore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terpsichore) (rhymes with "hickory").

Comment: Not to mention Persephone. Rhymes with phoney, not "pursey phone."

Comment: Ah, and Penelope, not pronounced Penny-Lope.

Comment: Ouch.  Funny to think that I've been able to pronounce 'terpsichorean' correctly, but would've missed badly on 'Terpsichore'.

Comment: People just need more Greek in their lives.

Answer (score 6):

*Infrared*.  Took me a while in my early teens to figure out that this is not equivalent in construction to words like "inflamed", and therefore is not pronounced "in-FRAIR'd"; the prefix is "infra-" and therefore the word is pronounced "In-fruh-RED".

Comment: Nice. "My foot itches but it doesn't look red. It's not inflamed; it's only infrared."

Answer (score 6):

Shibboleth.

Maybe not anymore.

Comment: just don't pronounce it Sibboleth

Comment: Something untimely might happen

Answer (score 5):

**Arkansas** - Americans may get it right, but to most of the rest of the world it looks like "Are Kansas"

> **Potpourri** - I've heard it called Pot-pour-ee. Though, admittedly, it's not common
>
> **nuclear** - Many say "Nyuu-kyuh-lur"
>
> **foyer** - It's "foy-ay". Not "foy-er"
>
> **Leicester square** - (Less-ter square) Only added because it's a famous place in London, otherwise place names are always unpredictably difficult.

Best I could come up with at the moment. Of course, there are Britishisms, or Scottish words like *ceilidh* or *niobh* (pronounced "Kay-lee and Neeve" respectively) but these words aren't common enough to enter into most people's regular lexicon and are borrowed from other languages.

Comment: All the American dictionaries I checked (*Merriam-Webster*, *Random House*, *American Heritage*) not only list “FOY-er” as a valid pronunciation for *foyer*, but they list it first (read: preferred).

Comment: Residents of Kansas usually pronounce the name of the Arkansas river as "are KAN ziss". The state is always "ARE can saw"

Comment: Funny that... I always thought that Americans knew it was "ARE-kan-saw" as they'd have learned it in school, no? I know in Canada, you hear both the right and wrong pronunciation, and I'd imagine it's the same in UK. As for foyer... it comes from a French word, so I'm not surprised American dictionaries get it wrong (from a French point of view).

Comment: @Atømix: Americans know it, but the Arkansas River in Kansas is different. It's *our Kansas* River. (If that doesn't sound right, keep in mind that *our* generally sounds like *are* in mid-America.)

Comment: @mmyers: That's awesome.

Comment: I participated in one group that defined "nucular" as "of or pertaining to a really huge explosion."  Too bad it's also used in botany...

Comment: I think it's Niamh, not Niobh... unless those are both in circulation?  (Wouldn't entirely surprise me.)

Comment: @thesunneversets : I have a friends called Niobh and Siobhan. Both pronounced like a "V". Perhaps Niamh is Irish? Both languages are similar.

Comment: @Atomix: Oh year, Niamh is probably Irish.  That would make sense!

Comment: You do see Anglicised spellings of a lot of the names that come from Gaelic - Shaun for Séan, Neve (as in Campbell) for Niobh/Niamh, etc.  Once you realise that they are the same name, you can often do a better job of guessing the ones you don't know.

Comment: The river is apparently pronounced the same as the state: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkansas_River#Pronunciations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkansas#Toponym

Comment: It is all named after the Kanza indians, so it should all be pronounced ar-KAN-zas.  (Full disclosure: I'm from Kansas.)

Comment: As another (former) Kansan I can verify that the river is definitely the *ar-kan-zis* river in the state of Kansas and the *ar-kan-saw* river in the state of Arkansas. The Wikipedia article now also notes that Coloradans also pronounce it *ar-kan-zis*.

Comment: @MatthewFrederick It may well say that, but I’ve an uncle who for many years was a river-runner on the Arkansas River here in Colorado, and **he** always said it with the *-saw* kind of ending, like the name of the state.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu |oǒ'boǒntoō|

I always thought it was oo-BUN-too.

([source](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu))

Comment: I always thought it was so natural to say it the right way, and then had absolutely no idea what people were talking about when they said "oo-BUN-too" or "you-BUN-too". True story.

Comment: I live in a central African country where that word would be pronounced "oo-boon-hoo", with a silent T, if you can imagine that.

Comment: Uh-oh... I have been mispronouncing this for years...

Answer (score 5):

Carotid.   /kəˈrɒtɪd/ It is a big artery in the neck. Not sure where the stress goes, but it goes in an unnatural place.

Comment: I think it's pronounced "cuh-RAW-tid." I originally thought it was "KAY-row-tid."

Comment: US: cuh-ROT-tid.  Cuh-RAW-tid sounds British to me.

Comment: In RP (British English), it's also cuh-ROT-tid, not cuh-RAW-tid. Amusingly, RAW would seen to most RP speakers to be indicative of a drawl, which would seem decidedly American.

Comment: Y'know, my parents did go to veterinary school in Georgia... Oh dear. It could be a Southern/ East coast thing. Some dialects pronounce the words "hawk" and "hock" identically. I don't. The "o" in "carotid" rhymes with the "aw" in "hawk" when I say it. The "o"s in "hock" and "rot" rhyme when I say them. Who knows why?

Comment: I intuitively want to pronounce it as "carroted" which I suppose is what happens when you have just had a lot of carrots thrown at you.

Comment: Or if you are garroted with a carrot.

Answer (score 5):

Two for me:

**parsimony**    Brit.  /ˈpɑːsᵻməni/ , U.S.  /ˈpɑrsəˌmoʊni/

**boatswain**   /ˈbəʊtsweɪn/ , usually  /ˈbəʊs(ə)n/

Answer (score 4):

The British pronunciation of "vitamin" must have been based on someone reading it. Note that the word was invented by an American, and it's a contraction of "vital" and "amine", so it should have been pronounced "vai-tah-min" but British people read it as "vit-ah-min".

As it happens, the British pronunciation has actually gone into other languages, so e.g. Japanese has a word "bitamin" based on the British mistaken pronunciation.

> "In 1912 Polish biochemist Kazimierz
>   Funk isolated the same complex of
>   micronutrients and proposed the
>   complex be named "Vitamine" (a
>   compound of **"vital amine"**).[12] The
>   name soon became synonymous with
>   Hopkins' "accessory factors", and by
>   the time it was shown that not all
>   vitamins were amines, the word was
>   already ubiquitous. In 1920, Jack
>   Cecil Drummond proposed that the final
>   "e" be dropped to deemphasize the
>   "amine" reference, after researchers
>   began to suspect that not all
>   "vitamines" (particularly vitamin A)
>   had an amine component."

Comment: @cindi: Thanks for the info. I have added a quote to the article from Wikipedia which was too long to fit into a comment. That might be wrong of course though.

Comment: @cindi: don't give up!

Comment: @Cindi, I always pronounced "vitae" with a long i...which is consistent with the proper pronunciation for vitamin. Actually, I've never heard anyone pronounce vitae without a long i.

Comment: Several Japanese dictionaries state that the Japanese word “bitamin” came from the _German_ word “Vitamin,” where the first vowel is short (rather than the said British pronunciation of “vitamin”).  If you read Japanese, please check http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%83%93%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0 and http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%83%93%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0.

Comment: Another british pronunciation that came as a shock to me when I went over there is yogurt. Americans say yo-gert (long o) and the British say your-gert (short o), with less 'r' in 'your', and a clipped 'gert'. I prefer the long o.

Answer (score 4):

Disheveled /dɪˈʃɛvəld/

I always read it as dis-HEAVE-eld.  I was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Adage.

I hear this spoken so rarely even right now I question whether I remember the right pronunciation. I always want to say a-dage (with "age" pronounced like the actual word "age").

Comment: You mean it has another pronunciation?

Comment: @neil: Yes, the original french one :-)

Answer (score 4):

I literally just learned a month ago (25 years into my existence!) that the h IS pronounced in herbivore. There are two kickers to this-- the first one being I was corrected by a 5 year old, and the second one being I have been vegetarian for 15 years!

Comment: @Rhodri: Right, General American has it with silent /h/ in all but a few rather urban accents.

Comment: I've pretty much given up on words that start with 'h'. I was taught in school a million years ago that 'hour' and 'honest' were exceptions to the general rule of sounding the 'h', except in Britain, where leading 'h' was rarely sounded. Fast forward 50 years and now I've got people telling me I'm pronouncing these things incorrectly.

Comment: British English always pronounces the H on herb.

Comment: In the central US, this is certainly pronounced erb-i-vore more often that herb-i-vore, tho both are frequent.

Answer (score 4):

The US state of Oregon is commonly mispronounced, even by Americans, as "Oh-ree-gawn." I've even heard this mispronunciation on national news programs. It's actually pronounced "Ory-gun".

I also come from the Willamette Valley of Oregon, which produces some great wines. To those vinophiles out there, please note it is "Will-lamb-it", emphasis on second syllable, not "William-etty" as some mistakenly say.

Comment: In Virginia, we pronounce Oregon more or less like organ. If I were to pronounce it very slowly, it would come out as "Or-rig-unn." I'd probably laugh if I heard "Oh-ree-gawn," though. That's funny!

Comment: For the life of me I can't get the stress on the second syllable of Willamette. I say WILL-uh-met, and it's really hard to stress "uh".

Comment: @JPmiaou: just think godDAMmit, Willamette.

Comment: @moioci That's awesome!  And a great way to remember how to say it :)  godDAMmit and willAMette both rhyme!

Comment: @Rosey28 You are very wrong:  **/ˈɔrəˌgɑn/ is not a mispronunciation;** it is a regional one, and quite a common one at that.  I suppose you say ‘France’ with an **æ**, too, don’t you?  Did you know that that’s wrong?

Answer (score 4):

**Antipodes**    /ænˈtɪpədiːz/

Apparently it's not pronounces anti-podes

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antipodes lists that as an acceptable alternative pronunciation.

Comment: Though the singular is pronounces like that.

Answer (score 4):

I'm so late to the party, but I can't resist.

Words with silent letters like **subtle**, (not sub-tel), **receipt**, (not reseept).

And others like **lettuce** (not lett-yuse).

**Panacea** ( Brit.  /ˌpanəˈsɪə/,  /ˌpanəˈsiːə/, U.S.  /ˌpænəˈsiə/) Besides "pa-ne-see-ya", why can't it be "pe-nay-shuh"? Or "pa-ne-ka" like Q. Boudicea,

Finally, when I was a kid, **Don Kwikzote** for **Don Quixote** (kee yo tay)

IPA: /dɒn kiˈhoʊteɪ/, /dõŋ kiˈχote/

Comment: Quixote is not "kee yo tay" but more like "kee ho teh".

Comment: @CesarGon: Yes, you are right. I've been thinking about it since I put it up because I realise there's more of an 'h' sound in Quixote.Thanks.

Comment: Unlike _quixotic_, which is derived from his name but is most commonly kwig-ZOT-ik.

Answer (score 4):

**Albeit** - pronounced "ahl-bee-it", and not "ahl-bite"

Comment: Even harder to guess if you know German :)

Answer (score 4):

Can't believe no one has mentioned "cache".  It's pronounced "cash".  It's like nails on a chalkboard every time I hear someone say "cashay"

Comment: The /cash-ay/ pronunciation is a different word, [cachet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cachet)

Answer (score 3):

**threshold**   OED: /ˈθrɛʃəʊld/  /ˈθrɛʃhəʊld/

I always thought it was “thres-hold”, just like “uphold” is “up-hold” and not “uf-old”. Eventually, turned out that “threshold” is one of the most written/spoken-wise consistent words in English.

Comment: I always assumed that the word is actually thresh-hold, just spelled more compactly.

Comment: I don't get it; “uf-old”? E.g. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/threshold) says threshold is pronounced /ˈθɹɛʃhəʊld/, just like I thought it would be.

Comment: “uphold” is a composite word (up + hold); “threshold” isn't, but in my mind I considered it as such (the *evanescent* ;) thres + hold). Mistakenly, which is the point of the question.

Comment: According to at least one theory of the etymology, threshold is a composite word (thresh+hold), but if so it isn't pronounced like one.

Answer (score 3):

**Cacophony**   /kæˈkɒfənɪ/

Until about two years ago, I was pronouncing it Cack-ah-phoney. I finally found out after saying it in front of my friends and they all burst out laughing. :(

Answer (score 3):

**Buoy**.  The number of people I meet who pronounce this boo-ee (instead of boy, as I pronounce it) staggers me.  Is "buoyant" to be pronounced "boo-ee-ant" also?

Comment: Nope, the adjective is almost always "boy-ant". Similarly, "bouy" is pronounced much closer to "boy" when used in its verbal forms. It's only the noun that is very clearly "boo-ee".

Comment: @res: I've looked it up and it's only in the UK where "boy" is the standard pronunciation.  I guess I'll let the Americans off, in a to-may-to/to-mah-to kind of way.  But it still sounds so wrong to my poor English ears!

Comment: Strange, I've only heard boo-ee, then again I speak west-coast American English.

Comment: It's "boo-ee" on the East coast, too.

Comment: I've also heard it pronounced closer to BOH-ee, not unlike the last name of singer David Bowie, which is different than the way Americans pronounce the last name of pioneer Jim Bowie, who lends his name to the large, sheathed knife, and is pronounced BOO-ee.

Comment: I have always found this word perplexing. And of course buoyant, 5 vowels in a row !

Comment: @ogerard: and the words are queueing up to exhibit five vowels in a row...Funny; that gets a red wiggly line.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: nice.

Comment: @ogerard No, *y* is a consonant there, not a vowel.

Answer (score 3):

Years ago, I was familiar with (and sometimes used) the spoken word **superfluous**. I also sometimes read the word spelled “superfluous” but pronounced it /SOO-per-FLOO-us/.

I had *no idea* that these were the same word.

Comment: Really, the only thing different is the accent.

Answer (score 3):

### Goon Show

Mispronounced as the "Go On Show" by the Governor of the BBC (or maybe it was a BBC Head of Department)

[Quote:](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aF5J18dFh3WIJ%3ascaryduck.blogspot.com/2003_10_01_archive.html+BBC+governor+to+ask+what,+exactly,+this+%E2%80%9CGo+On+Show%E2%80%9D&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)

> “Those Crazy People”, leading one BBC
>   governor to ask what, exactly, this
>   "Go On Show" was all about.

Answer (score 3):

- Iron (mispronounced by some as I-run)
- Dais (mispronounced by some as dias)
- Greenwich (mispronounced by some as green witch)
- niche (mispronounced by some as nike)
- orchid (mispronounced by some as or-cheed)
- Maoist (mispronounced by some as may-ost)
- Debris (mispronounced by some as deb-ris)
- Tupple (mispronounced by some as tyu-ple)

Comment: Usually, in pronunciations a hyphen delineates syllables. Have you really heard orchid and debris pronounced as three syllables?

Comment: The hyphens I used were not to separate the syllables but to highlight the pronunciation. Edits made

Comment: I had debris growing up. Gave my family a good laugh on that one.

Comment: *tyu-ple* is in fact the correct British pronunciation. And it's actually spelt "tuple". Both of these are because it comes from words like "quintuple", "sextuple" and so on.

Answer (score 3):

**Beribboned**

"Be-ribboned", not "berry-boned"!

Comment: You should have known to split it at the bb so it would have been Berib-boned.

Answer (score 3):

I have never forgotten the pronunciation of 'fatigue' since mispronouncing it at an early age. I said 'fat-ig-you' rather than the correct 'fat-ee-g' (with a hard g).

Comment: And that store that sells the old junk is the auntie-Q shop. :)

Comment: Always funny to me as "fatigue" in french only means tiredness and has no clear relation for us to cloth. I remember having a hard time understanding why this word was occuring in a military novel.

Comment: The correct is not fat-eeg but fa-TEEG.

Comment: Or my favorite pronunciation, fa-TIG-you-eee

Answer (score 3):

detritus - dih-TRY-tis

desultory - DES-ul-tory

Comment: Wha?  It's not de-SULT-or-ee and DET-ri-tus?

Answer (score 3):

One of the most commonly mispronounced words is *forte*, as in one's strong point.  It's really supposed to be pronounced just like *fort*, but most people use two syllables.  I think the mispronunciation may become so common that descriptivist dictionaries will list it on equal footing (some already list it as a variant).

Comment: You can't win with this one.  People will look at you funny either way.

Comment: I say "fort".  Oddly, even though pretty much everyone says "forte", I don't recall ever getting challenged on it.

Comment: It should only be your forte if you can fire a cannone out of it.

Answer (score 3):

I think British and American pronunciation and spelling of the word 'aluminum' are different.  Americans place the emphasis on a long 'OO' in the second syllable, whereas the British place the emphasis on a short 'i' in the third syllable and include another 'i' before the last 'u' (aluminium).

Answer (score 3):

**Subterfuge.** I always though the 'b' was silent, like in 'subtle,' but it's not.

Wrong: sut-ter-fuge
Right: sub-ter-fuge

Answer (score 3):

Gauge

I think it's pronounced "gay-dzj", while my Dutch colleagues pronounce it "gow-tsj" and frown upon me.

Comment: You are correct.  Your friend may be thinking of the word 'gouge', which means to 'cut a groove' or 'to chisel'.  The two words **look** very similar.

Answer (score 3):

**dais**   /ˈdeɪɪs/,  /deɪs/

I always want to pronounce it DAYS.  Apparently it's pronounced DIE-us or DAY-us.

Comment: Erm, the two pronunciations you yourself give, rhyme with ‘day(u)s’. I pronounce it like ‘days’, except with an unvoiced /s/, rather than the plural phoneme /z/.

Answer (score 2):

`Quark`   /kwɑːrk/, /kwɔːrk/

Murray Gellman insisted on `kvork` pronunciation, while it was supposed to rhyme with 'bark' in the original poem, "Three quarks for Muster Mark!/Sure he hasn't got much of a bark/And sure any he has it's all beside the mark."

Ridiculously, outside english it is pronounced as `kvark`.

Comment: I've only heard it pronounced "kwark".

Comment: There's a program called [Quarks&Co](http://www.wdr.de/tv/quarks/) on German television, [whose host](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranga_Yogeshwar) pronounces it "kwɑːk" (he holds a PhD in physics). The German Wikipedia [gives](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_%28Physik%29) the German pronunciation as [kwɔrk], [kwɑːk] or [kwɑrk].

Comment: Murray Gellman invented the name "quark" and the correct pronunciation is indeed "kwork" rhyming with "dork" rather than "kwark" rhyming with "ark". An alternative proposal for the name was the "three aces".

Comment: If he wanted it pronounced as "quork", he should've spelled it that way. Given that he didn't, I will continue to say "kwark" (to rhyme with 'bark').

Comment: I thought James Joyce had misspelt *quarts*, as in double pints

Answer (score 2):

How about "recipe"? First time I saw it, I thought "ree-sipe", not "reh-sih-pee".

Answer (score 2):

I live in Texas where they LOVE to name places with spellings that imply a common pronunciation, but have a completely different one.

**Some real examples:**

**Manor** - Pronounced **"May-ner"**. A city near my home. The town is named after a family with that pronunciation of their name.

**Elgin** - Pronounced with a hard G. Another nearby city. The famous basketball player who pronounced it with a soft-g throws everyone off on that one.

**Bois d' Arc** - Pronounced **"bo dark"**. A street named after a local variety of tree.

**Manchaca** - Pronounced **"man shack"**. A city named after some Native American word.

**Pedernales** -Pronounced **"[pur-deh-NAH-liss](http://inogolo.com/pronunciation/d1109/Pedernales)"**. A nearby river. Probably

**Bexar** - Pronounced **"bear"**. The county containing San Antonio.

You may think some of these are just a result of local accents, but no. They are the official pronunciations of these places.

Comment: The correct pronunciation of a place name is how the majority of people who live there say it. I know of no exceptions in English.

Comment: can’t forget Mexia, pronounced “muh-HAY-uh”

Comment: @nohat - Henceforth known as the birthplace of Anna Nicole Smith.

Comment: Cities are particularly bad.  Moscow, ID is pronounced "MOSS-ko" even though they same people pronounce Moscow, Russia as "MOSS-cow"

Comment: I was baffled by Sanger where I stayed when I visited TX.

Comment: How about countries. It is Ear-ahn not Eye-ran (Iran) and Ear-ahk not Eye-rack (Iraq)

Comment: Found this pronunciation guide for Texas places. A clear indicator that this is an issue in the state. (http://www.texasalmanac.com/images/TownPronunciationGuide.pdf)

Comment: There's a Houston County, GA, pronounced "HOW-stun", in contrast to Texas's more famous "HYOO-stun".

Comment: @Mitch there is also a street in NYC with the same name/pronunciation.

Comment: @Neil Fein: what about Missouri?  I have relatives from there who say "Mizz-ur-uh", and I just can't bring myself to view that as correct.

Comment: Since you bring up Texas, I have to relate Koenig Lane in Austin, which is locally pronounced "KAY-nig."  Having learned a little German, this makes me cringe, but as Mr. Fein relates, I can't call it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For quite a long time I pronounced persimmon as "PER-simmon" instead of the correct "per-SIM-mon".

Answer (score 2):

**Mishap**

Who hasn't said mish-ap instead of mis-hap?

Answer (score 2):

There are some technical words that are commonly mistaken:
SCSI: Correct: scuzzy. Wrong: Sexy ;)

Comment: Isn't that an acronym for "Small Computer Serial Interface" and not a word? In that case I'd argue that there is no correct way to say it, only preferences.

Comment: @JohnFx: In much the same way we do not say "Sharks with fricken light amplification by stimulated emmision of radiations on their heads", you are wrong.

Comment: The inventor, who also coined the acronym, intended /sexy/ as the pronunciation. Another engineer on the standardization committee countered with the antonymous alternative and it stuck.

Comment: Sorry but there's nothing sexy about SCSI.  Scuzzy it is, on general principle.

Answer (score 2):

**Corollary**   /kɒˈrɒlərɪ/,  /ˈkɒrələrɪ/

I have always pronounced and heard this word as KOR-uh-lar-ee but recently found out that my wife pronounces it kor-AW-lar-ee (I guess like the Brits, if dictionary.com is to be believed).  I thought this might have been from her growing up in a small town, but how often are people saying "corollary" in a small town anyway??  Where she picked up the British pronunciation, I'll never know.

Comment: +1 because I never could keep it straight in high school math proofs.

Comment: Honestly, I've heard both, from tenured math professors. The British profs put the "proper" emphasis. Everyone else just says whatever and moves on to the proof :D

Comment: Maybe she learned it from the same place my brother learned to pronounce 'esophagus' as E-so-FOG-us (where that E is a 'short' e as in bed). From a school teacher :)

Answer (score 2):

**agate**

Although I know it is pronounced **ag-it**, I so badly want to say **ag-gat** whenever I see it in print.

Comment: A-sitting on agate?

Comment: And I was taught to pronounce it A-gee with a hard 'g'. I distinctly remember the teacher telling us that the marbles we called 'agees' were called that because of the resemblance to agate.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Doc Brown was right, in a way. The historically accurate way to pronounce the prefix giga- is with a j-sound (as in jigabyte).

I think this is the best example of a collective "say it before you heard it". It seems the people in the circles the prefix came into first use (mainly the sciences) didn't ever take a class in ancient greek (not that I ever have either), or recognize that other words with the same etymology (giant and gigantic are pronounced jiant and jigantic) are inconsistent with this pronunciation. But the pronunciation has stuck so what can you do.

Also, as an afterthought - **Colonel**. Who the hell came up with that? It took me years to recognize that Colonel and "Kernel" is the same rank.

Comment: At least the widespread pronunciation of *gigabyte* is internally consistent. Can't say the same for *gigantic*.

Comment: I suspect the computer industry is to blame for the shift from "jigga" to "gigga". But as "wrong" as it is, I shudder when I hear someone say "jiggabytes".

Comment: Where did you get the idea that “giga” is historically pronounced /dʒiga/? *Historically*, the word comes from Greek, started with a γ and was, by very widespread consensus, pronounced /g/ in Ancient Greek (and as a voiced velar fricative in Modern Greek, neither of which sound anything like /dʒ/). Furthermore, the prefix was proposed by a German-speaking member of the IEC and there is no /dʒ/ sound in German so I doubt (though I don’t know) that the proposal intended the /dʒ/ pronunciation.

Comment: @Martha:  Well, <i>gigantic</i> follows the "rule" that 'i', 'e', and 'y' make the 'g' sound like 'j'.  That is why 'u' commonly comes into play as a helper (<i>guess</i>, <i>guile</i>, etc.).  [Hmm... how do you make italics in comments?]

Comment: @John Y, `*italic*` and `**bold**` work in comments.

Answer (score 2):

awry, caveat, nomenclature

Answer (score 2):

I didn't pronounce "hegemony" correctly until I was embarrassingly old.

And what about "Chaise longue?"

Then again, I like to pronounce "baseline" so it rhymes with "Vaseline."

Comment: I am unreasonably fond if "horses doovers"

Comment: @ראובן: *Chaise longue* is pronounced differently in different places.  In British English it approximates the French pronunciation, but in (at least some varieties of) US English it’s typically pronounced as *lounge* — presumably originally in error, but now established as standard.

Comment: @PLL: Maybe so, but it's misspelled as often as it's mispronounced. Yes language evolves, but it's hard for me to accept a blatant error as "standard."

Comment: @ראובן: brought up in the UK and so only hearing the roughly authentic version until I moved to the US, I also find this example really jarring (both the spelling and the pronunciation).  But… well, would you call the way most English-speakers pronounce *Paris* a blatant error?  True, it’s established more widely throughout English, and has been for much longer.  But in some American speech communities, *lounge* has been (I think) standard for a good generation or two; so how can I in conscience condemn it there, without condemning my own *Paris*?

Answer (score 2):

Entrée (ˈɑːntreɪ) - I pronounced it as Ent-ree (Almost the same way you would spell Entry ). I did not lookup the history, but felt the pronunciation weird

Genre (ˈʒɑːnrə) - I still feel a little awkward pronouncing this. Gen-er was my natural pronunciation of this (though one would argue that Gen-re would be close to the spelling :) ).

Comment: Having grown up playing video games and reading sci fi and fantasy I felt very dumb telling people about my favorite jen-RAY.

Answer (score 1):

**comfortable** /ˈkʌmfətəb(ə)l/

It's pronounced “cumftible”, while I as a foreigner (furriner :) thought it was “cumfort-ible”

Comment: As a native English (US) speaker, I variously say "cum-fort-i-bel" or "cum-fert-i-bel" or "cumf-ter-bel".

Comment: That reminds me of a joke that an Indian(from India) friend used to tell me in an Indian accent. "Are you comfortable (come for table)"? "No, I came for tea". Said in an Indian accent, it's hilarious!

Comment: @Atømix: and the traffic cop to the recently arrived Far-eastern immigrant, who was nearly run over by a car: “Hey, mister, did you come here to die?” “No! I cahm hear yester-die!”

Comment: @Gary: if any native English speaker says "cum-fort-i-bel" I'll eat my hat.

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock: Is that with a short *i* or a long *i*? If it's the short one, I hope your hat is tasty.

Comment: @gary: Why do you vary the word pronunciation?

Comment: @Vinko, I don't know why, it's not a conscious decision. Maybe I just never picked up that one pronunciation is more popular than another.

Comment: @Ex-user, sorry for adding fiber to your diet!

Comment: To be honest, I've never heard it pronounced "cumftible".

Comment: @neil: I've heard it as “cumftible” by British people.

Answer (score 1):

Place names from the early US are an endless source of confusion:

- Many places in the US are named "Berkeley" and are pronounced "Burkly", but they are all(?) named after Sir William Berkeley, whose name is(was?) pronounced like Charles   Barkley, the basketball player.
- Cairo, Illinois is pronounced "KAY-row", not like the place with the pyramids.
- Versailles, Kentucky is pronounced "ver-SAILS", not like the place with the palace.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how would you pronounce Cairo, Egypt?

Comment: to rhyme with pie hole.

Comment: @Joel Spolsky: Cai-hole? Cai-role? I'm not following... or else I am, and it disturbs me.

Comment: It's "Ky-row," Egypt, but "Kay-row," Georgia.

Comment: Oh. Got it. For some reason I was pronouncing KAY in my head as KYE. It all makes sense now.

Comment: Can’t forget San Jose, Illinois (san joez)

Comment: La-FAY-ette, AL

Comment: French people probably shudder when they hear Baton (BAT-en rather than bah-TON) Rouge.

Comment: This is normal, though. There's a hamlet in the south of Denmark originally settled by returned emigrants from the States. They named it The Valley; it is now horrifyingly pronounced /te 'væly/ (the e as in French ‘café’, the y as in French ‘tu’ or German ‘süß’).

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday, I heard someone on NPR pronounce "secreted", as in to have concealed or hidden something. Never having heard the word spoken before, I've always assumed it is pronounced secret-ed and not secrete-ed as he said.

Comment: The NPR person was wrong, then. The emphasis is on the first syllable when it's the past tense of *secret*, and on the second syllable when it's the past tense of *secrete*. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/secreted

Comment: Oops! So much for that one. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: You really don't want to secrete anything you don't mean to, in particular not to be secreted away.

Answer (score 1):

When I was in a spelling bee, the enunciator said AT-wit-ter, as in "The birds were all atwitter." (should be a-TWIT-ter)

Comment: +1 because that's not even a rare word.

Answer (score 1):

*Pseudo* is also one of the mispronounced words. Some people say it Pee-see-doo, where the correct pronunciation is soo-doe (american) or sew-doe (English)

Comment: I have a co-worker who pronounces it "suede-o."

Comment: I has a coworker who said "puh-suede-oh". It took me a few minutes to figure out what he was trying to say. I didn't correct him though.

Comment: @Boofus McGoofus: I would hope suede-o is for comic emphasis.

Comment: The American pronunciation is close to su-doh.  I can't exactly tell how that is different from your `sew-doe` that you have listed for British.

Answer (score 1):

'Rendezvous' is one that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

"Minuscule" is often mispronounced and misspelled as "miniscule".

"Err" is often mispronounced as "air".

"Long-lived" and "short-lived" are too often pronounced with a short I sound. It means long or short "life", not as in the verb "to live".

Comment: The difference between "minuscule" and "miniscule" is so, ahem, minuscule as to make no difference. (Sorry, had to say it.) Dunno if I've ever heard "air" for "err". As for long- or short-lived, both pronunciations are now considered correct, and more people use the short-i than the long-i. (It also makes sense that way - English often uses the past tense of verbs as adjectives. Borrowed time, linked cause, forwarded email...)

Comment: minuscule is not derived from mini - rather minus.  See the etymology.  Long/short-lived also regards life, not the verb to live.  Our language is being spoiled.  Just because most people use it one way does not make it correct.  I have heard surveys that people can't find Africa on a world map - does that mean it is ok?  Accepting ignorance and watering down the language to the lowest common denominator is not the answer...

Comment: @Martha, Everyone where I come from (Hanover, Virginia) that I heard say err pronounced it as air. If I've ever heard it pronounced differently, I didn't recognize it or don't remember.

Comment: @Tim, (1) etymology has never governed pronunciation. (See many of the examples in this topic.) And despite what the French think, language change is not automatically equivalent to language ruination. (2) I know that the correct *spelling* of minuscule is with two u's, but the *pronunciation* difference between an unstressed *i* and an unstressed *u* is so small as to be nonexistent. Sorry if I wasn't clear. :)

Comment: Where else does one EVER pronounce u as a short i?  It is just plain wrong.

Comment: What is the "correct" pronunciation of "Err" if not "air"? In Canada, we say "to air is human".

Comment: As far as I know it is "er"er

Comment: @Tim, note the "unstressed": in most varieties of English, unstressed vowels are indistinguishable from each other, because they all become schwas. So I can see including "minuscule" on a list of frequently *misspelled* words, but not on a list of frequently *mispronounced* words.

Comment: It is mispronounced - as "miniscule".  short i is not a short u

Comment: Err has the same root as error or errant.  Perhaps the problem some people have with it being pronounced as 'air' is not that 'err' is mispronounced, but that 'air' is pronounced differently in different regions.  In mid-western America, the beginning vowel sound in 'err' and 'air' is pronounced closer to a short 'e', not as the diphthong used to pronounced the letter 'A'.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New, I'm with you.  I've lived and travelled all over the US and have never heard anyone pronounce "err" any other way than exactly the same as the first syllable in error or errant.

Comment: For *minuscule* it seems a lot of pronunciations have co-existed for a while.  The OED lists “Brit.  /ˈmɪnᵻskjuːl/, /ˈmɪnjᵿskjuːl/, /mɪˈnʌskjuːl/, U.S. /ˈmɪnəˌskjul/”.

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy  Brit.  /ˈakjᵿrəsi/, U.S.  /ˈækjərəsi/

When I first learned the word, (in first grade, from a pokemon game,) I thought it was Akyur-uh-see).

Comment: Come to think of it, how many people mispronounce "Pokemon" (Poke-ay-mon) as (Poke-ee-man)?

Comment: For what it's worth, "akyur-uh-see" is the most common pronunciation for American English speakers.

Comment: @res - I *am* American.

Comment: I have to agree, I've only ever heard "ack-yer-ussy."

Answer (score 1):

The word "Dickensian".  I read this word many times before I heard someone say it.  I always pronounced this with the accent on the first syllable, exactly as it is with "Dickens".  Then I heard someone else say it with the accent on the second syllable.  And then I heard another person say it that way.  And then I had a person 'correct' me when I said it with the accent on the first syllable.

Actually, this doesn't really answer your question, because I think it should be pronounced with the accent on the first syllable.  It doesn't make sense to me that you would pronounce "Dickensian" with an accent on a different syllable than the accented syllable in "Dickens".

Comment: OED says it is pronounced with stress on -en-.

Comment: You're right that it doesn't make much sense, but English is like that. The reign of Queen E **liz** abeth I was the Eliza **beth** an period... (apologies for formatting!)

Answer (score 1):

For a long time I pronounced Epitome as "Epi-tome" when I saw the word in print. Funny thing is that I was aware of the prononciation "Epi-to-me", but subconsciously assumed that it was a different word. I had much else on my mind, I guess, to investigate. I am now enlightened.

Comment: I did the exact same thing. I knew what an "epitome" was, and thought 'epitomy" must be something different...

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-words-are-commonly-mispronounced-by-literate-people-who-read-them-before-the/1685#1685

Answer (score 1):

Meringue.  Recently heard this pronounced as Mare-ing-you instead of meh-rang. Also the Irish name Niamah, pronounced Neeve (rhymes with eve) seems to cause a great deal of confusion.

Comment: Niamh, not Niamah.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i have some words

- Subtle ( Pronounced "suttle")   /ˈsʌt(ə)l/
- Panache (I have heard that this is pronounced "punash".)   /pəˈnæʃ/

Answer (score 1):

Corps (as in Marine Corps)

Being french I pronounced it cohr, not core like most Americans...

Comment: Brits don't pronounce the p either. The Beatles (which is a bad pun) have a publishing company called Apple Corps (another bad pun).

Comment: In the US, Corps is short for corporations, and is pronounced "corpse" (fittingly, on occasion).

Comment: Didja hear about the Marine who received a dishonorable discharge?  They said he was rotten to the Corps...

Answer (score 1):

**Emeritus** - was told about someone who pronounced the word as if it were a disease (emphasis on a long I.)

For those unfamiliar with this title, the root word is 'merit' and the emphasis is placed on 'mair'.

Answer (score 1):

**debris**   /dɛˈbriː/

"Debris" took me a few years to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Just picked up two/three new ones today.

The first: I read that blog Cakewrecks, having never baked a cake myself. So when I saw the word "fondant," I assumed with the great knowledge gained from my three years of high school French that it was pronounced the French way, something like "fund-AUN(T)"...Of course, my sister's getting married and came by to make a practice wedding cake, which would be decorated with "FAWND-unt."...Which inevitably led to an argument, and led to my embarrassment...

The second (and third) I learned are revocable and irrevocable. Revoke is pronounced with emphasis on the second syllable, in my case as "rivv-OAK." Naturally, I assumed that (ir)revocable was pronounced "(EAR-)revv-OAK-ibble." It is not. It is pronounced "(ear-)REVV-uck-ubble."

EDIT: Turns out I was either illiterate or enjoyed being punished that day because "(EAR-)revv-OAK-ibble" is a valid alternative pronunciation according to Merriam-Webster! M-W also says they're less common, but not how much so. Sorry about that!

Comment: Is google dictionary US first? or is [fondant](http://www.google.com/dictionary?aq=f&langpair=en|en&q=fondant&hl=en) actually pronounced that way in British English too?

Comment: @mplungjan: I checked the Cambridge Dictionary Online too. It has the same pronunciation (or nearly the same): http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/fondant

Comment: I've never heard REVV-uck-able.  I have heard an attorney discuss a reVOCable trust. (US)

Comment: @moioci It seems you're right. I just double-checked the pronunciation of (ir)revocable, and it turns out (ir)reVOCable is allowed, but apparently less common. Not sure how I missed that. I *never* miss an excuse to be right! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

**harbinger**

You'd think it to be "har-BING-er" when it's actually "HAR-bin-jer".

**infamous**

Always read "in-FAME-us" when it's "IN-fah-mus"

**facetious**

Looks like "FA-cet-us" when it's "fah-SEE-shus"

Answer (score 1):

When I was in the 8th or 9th grade, I read much much more than I spoke.   Then one day I was called on in class to challenge another classmate's perspective.

> I used the word "doubt" in a sentence.

The problem was is that I actually pronounced the "B" in "doubt".  Yes, try it.  It's kinda fun to do.

I realised I never actually said that word out loud before, but I went for it anyways.  The class was silent, and I thought I had made a convincing case.  Needless to say that's not why the class was slient.  Then moments later the class clown asked "Did you just say the B in doubt".  Everyone got a good laugh at my expense.

Not sure how common that error is, but I still think it's a funny story.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned place names, and [one answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2322) has mentioned that personal names "are tricky too".

I'd like to add that this happens to me pretty frequently with names in the news: I get my news from the radio, mostly, so when I first see a name in print it doesn't necessarily register immediately that it's the person I've been hearing about. This happened, for example, with the name [*Geithner*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timothy_Geithner), which is pronounced `/ˈgajtnɚ/` ("gight-ner"): when I read it, I thought it was `/ˈgejθnɚ/` ("gay-thner") for a moment.

Comment: Cairo, Illinois - Pronounced Kay-Ro

Answer (score 1):

"Cleansing" has a short "e" in the first syllable, so it rhymes with "hens." A friend in English pronounced it quite logically with a long "e" just like in the word "clean." We all kept quiet for a few minutes, expecting him to realise his mistake. We were, however, forced to take him to task. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's just me, but I pronounced *bedraggled* with two syllables ("bed" + "raggled") for years before I made the connection: "be" + "draggled".

I had always pictured torn bedclothes...!

Answer (score 1):

**Interminable:** /ɪnˈtɜrmɪnəbəl/

It has the prefix *inter-*, doesn't it? So it should clearly be accented on the first syllable, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It has the prefix of "in" meaning "not" combined with the word "terminable" mean "capable of being stopped or terminated".  Inter-minable would mean...  I have no idea.  Able to go between different mines?

Comment: @Kevin: I know that now. But I didn't when I first read and pronounced it as a child - I should have been clearer.

Comment: So the second part was sarcasm which I missed.  Am I allowed to give myself a "whoosh"?

Comment: I *know* sarcasm is invisible on the web. My bad.

Comment: Hear, hear. (It doesn't help that I have a genetic tendency to always put the stress on the first syllable.)

Answer (score 1):

"Sean" as  'shaun'

I pronounced it as 'seen' for a while!

Comment: I still do for Sean Bean - Seen Been!

Answer (score 1):

I only discovered a few days ago that ***chintz*** is apparently not a French word, but a Hindi one, and is therefore not pronounced ‘shints’, but exactly as it's spelt.

*Catenary* is another odd one—since no one ever says the word (at least it's never popped up in any conversations I've had), I had to look it up to find out whether it was KAY-tuh-neh-ry or kuh-TEE-nuh-ry. (It's the latter.)

Comment: Uh, nope, not here in the U.S. of A, it ain't.  It's CAT enary: http://visual.merriam-webster.com/pronunciation.php?id=transport-machinery/rail-transport/09884&title=catenary. (Just start typing "catenary pronu" into Google and you'll see "catenary **british** pronunciation" pop up as one of the suggestions.)

Answer (score 1):

Comptroller, pronounced kun-TROH-lur, not COMP-troh-lur. Even some comptrollers mispronounce it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure how to pronounce "gyro" -- the edible kind. Fortunately, I'm very sure how to eat one.

Comment: It's pronounced Yee-Row (as in Yee-hah Row-Boat)

Comment: I've always heard "hero".  And I've even seen it written that way sometimes: "hero sandwich".

Answer (score 1):

Detritus, which looks like and is often pronounced DE-tri-tus, but whose proper pronunciation is di-TRYT-us.

Answer (score 0):

As a young 1st-grader, I came home to tell my parents that I would be learning "MATH-ma-tics." Made sense to me that it would rhyme with arithmatic!

Much later I had similar experiences with "array" and "piezoelectric."

Answer (score 0):

This is more mis-read than mis-pronounced, but as a child, I read [The Magikan's Newph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magician%27s_Nephew) by C.S.Lewis.

Off-topic, but mis-*heard* stuff is often fun too (e.g. Harold be thy name - *can't find a decent link for that one*)

Comment: "Harold be thy name" sounds like a [mondegreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen).

Answer (score 0):

It was many years before I figured out that Arkan-SAW and Arkan-SAS were actually the same place:-)

Answer (score 0):

**Acolyte**  Brit.  /ˈakəlʌɪt/, U.S.  /ˈækəˌlaɪt/

In my head, it was "ah-colt". The correct pronunciation is "ah-col-ite".

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple that I've come across in philosophy.

Charles Sanders Peirce. It's pronounced like "purse" not like "pierce".

Qua. (Latin meaning "as"). Apparently should be pronounced "kway". I do not like this.

And as for the number of different ways I've heard people pronounce "Humean"...

Comment: OED gives both kway and kwah.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who like rugby..

**Llanelli**, a city of Wales, is pronounced 'clanecli'.

**Gloucester**, **Leicester**, as **Worcester** : 'Gloss-ter' 'Less-ter', 'Wuss-ter'

Comment: Gloss-ter, Less-ter (My home county), Wuss-ter.

Comment: Kaz is right here.

Comment: My bad, I was just pointing out the unpronounced "ce". I'll edit right away !

Comment: Clanecli is a very strange and misleading way of representing Llanelli. Hla-ne-hli would be closer.

Answer (score 0):

> Bayesian (pronounced BAYZ-ee-un)

Comment: How else would you pronounce it?

Comment: @Martha maybe one could think it was "bay-ess-ian", or ba-YESSI-an"?   If you know it's named after Bayes it's obvious, if not, it might not be.

Comment: @Martha, @TM: one might also expect the ending to rhyme with e.g. *Indonesian*.  The “think of whom it was named after” principle holds good in this case, but is misleading for *Cartesian*, which is named for *Descartes* (whose *-es* is silent, or almost so, depending on language), but is pronounced with stress on the *-es-*, and does indeed rhyme with *Indonesian*.

Answer (score 0):

**Oxymoron**   /ˌɒksɪˈmɔːrɒn/

Usually pronounced "ok-See-mawr-On" with the emphasis on the second and fourth syllables (i.e. Oxy plus Moron.) One of my high school English teachers would always mispronounce the word to make it sound ever so much better: ox-Zim-a-ron with the emphasis on the second syllable. This pronunciation makes the word almost poetic and I'll use it to this day but it does very much confuse people.

Comment: OED has pronunciation on -mo-.

Comment: I have always heard it (and said it) "OX-ee-MORE-ahn"....

Answer (score 0):

One that used to catch me out a lot was **"anxiety"**. I used to pronouce it as in "*anxious*"

Comment: French-style, alors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it isn't a good idea to continue discussing place names and personal, but the Irish have some beauties, including:

- Dun Laoghaire - dun-leery.

Answer (score 0):

**Ornery**  /ˈɔrn(ə)ri/

It's pronounced "awn-ree" or "awr-ner-ee".  It is not pronounced "or-ner-ee".

Comment: [Sure it is.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ornery)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there haven't been any answers for a while, so some of these may be new mispronunciations that have developed:

**homage** is now pronounced incorrectly by many supposedly educated people, including news announcers, as *uh-MAZH*, instead of the correct *AH-midg*.

similarly, **niche** is now pronounced incorrectly as *neesh* instead of the correct *nich*.

Comment: Oh! the irony . . .

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is the word **infrared**. I never, as a child, ever noticed that **infra-** prefix, and never thought the word had anything to do with **red**.

Naturally I pronounced it as in-FRAYRD, rhyming with "cared". I thought that **frared** must be some sort of word...I still percieve the word as "in-frared" in my head...

Answer (score 0):

**Debridement** - The medical procedure of stripping away gangrenous or infected tissue to allow healing.

It is frequently pronounced **De-Bride-Meant** (as in D - wedding bride - past tense of mean).  The proper pronunciation **Deh-Breed-Mont**.

Answer (score 0):

I got tripped up by **[Misogynist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/misogynist)** (a person who hates, dislikes, mistrusts, or mistreats women.) "Mi-so-guy-nist" when it's actually "mi-soj-uh-nist", as well as many others on this list.