# English letter sequence with most pronunciations

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

The letters *-ough-* can be pronounced a ridiculous number of different ways in English.  Here is a possibly incomplete list:

- tough, enough
- cough, trough
- bough, plough
- though, dough
- thought, bought
- through
- thorough, borough
- weirdos like hiccough, hough, lough.

Are there any other letter sequences in English near this crazy? How do non-English speakers cope with trying to learn a language as messy as this?

Comment: For what it's worth, *bough*, *plough*, *though*, *dough*, *thorough*, and *borough* all rhyme when I pronounce them.

Comment: @Martha: cool!  How do you pronounce them?  To rhyme with "go"?

Comment: @thesunneversets, yes, more or less. (Also note that I probably mispronounce bough and plough. It's the whole reading-vocabulary thing.)

Comment: For me: though, dough thorough and borough rhyme (with go) but bough and plough do not rhyme with go (they rhyme with cow).

Comment: My "though" rhymes with "go", but my "thorough" rhymes with "kookaburra" :D

Comment: I've got [ʌf], [ɒːf], [aʊ], [oʊ], [ɒːʔ], [uː], and [əʊ]. Fairly standard American, I should think, but even as a teenager I've been called old-fashioned-sounding a number of times on this site. And yes, I pronounce "caught" and "cot" differently. How else would you distinguish "haughty" from "hottie"?

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and new: as far as I know, *thorough* and *borough* in most (all?) UK dialects rhyme with *kookaburra* — the last vowel is a schwa — but in some (many?) US dialects they rhyme with *tomorrow* — the last vowel is [əʊ] as in *go* (but unstressed and a bit reduced).

Comment: @PLL: I guess you can include Canadian dialects (at least the ones I'm familiar with) in the same group as American for the thurough group. Now that you mention it, I've heard people say borough with a schwa. Well, that's Canadian English for you. Sometimes like UK, sometimes like US, sometimes unique.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: In my English, "haughty" and "hottie" are pronounced the same and you distinguish them by the position in the sentence, since one is an adjective and one is a noun. I wonder if someone created a haughty hottie website, but I'm afraid to search for that while at work. :p

Comment: It turns out that *hiccough* is a misspelling of *hiccup*. Honest! And *hough* /hɒk/ and *lough* /lɒx/ are both really interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to (2):

We memorize each exceptional word.  In the grand scheme of things, this is actually not a huge number of words.  Consider Chinese and Japanese, who have a large number meaning-based characters that provide little to no information about their pronunciation at all.  If memorizing the pronunciation of thousands of characters is possible, then memorizing English words with exceptional spelling seems almost trivial.

Comment: I guess English is far from being the hardest language in the world.  Nevertheless, whoever came up with the idea of consistent phonetic spelling throughout a language deserves a medal!

Comment: +1. A large number of Chinese characters are semanto-phonetic: half of the character gives you a clue as to pronunciation; the other half, meaning. So if you're a literate native speaker, you stand a pretty good chance of being able to figure out an unknown character. The problem is a bit more extreme in Japanese, which tends to use a single character for multiple related meanings, which are disambiguated by context given by phonetic characters. Each meaning typically has its own slightly different pronunciation, which may be derived from a Chinese word or a native Japanese one. Yeeeah.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn’t surpass it, but *ue* seems to at least be a modest little brother to *ough*.  It can represent:

- *\-yoo\*: argue, cue, ensue
- *\-oo\*: glue, true, sue
- [silent]: tongue, morgue, vague, the Hague
- *\-way\*: segue, suede

(This is just looking at the cases where it really is functioning as a unit, omitting examples like *truer* and *queer*, where a phoneme straddles its boundary.)

[Inspired by the comments [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-words-are-commonly-mispronounced-by-literate-people-who-read-them-before-the/1439#1439).]

Answer (score 2):

"al" can be pronounced

- /ɔ:l/: all, also
- /ɒl/ or /ɔl/: false
- /ɔ:/: talk
- /a:l/: dal, kraal, phall
- /a:/: half, calm, almond
- /əl/: usual, alone
- /æl/: analysis
- /æ/: salmon
- /eil/: halo
- /ei/: halfpenny, Ralph (by some)

OK, the case for /a:l/ is pretty weak -- I can't think of any examples except direct loans.

Comment: Indirect loans being?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What's the correct term, then? I mean direct from one language to another with no change except what is made necessary by the use of different writing systems. As opposed to, e.g. priest < L. presbyter < Gk presbyteros, or fancy < fantasy < Fr fantasie < L < Gr phantasia.

Comment: Loan (or loanword). 'Direct ...' is tautologous, and undesirable (not all tautologies are).

Comment: How about words like *logically* and *strategically*, where it's pronounced /l/?

Answer (score 0):

J. J can be pronounced as "wa" as in "marihuana" and "oh" as in "Jose'" and "Jae" as in Jacob and "jah" as in "jack"

Comment: And don't forget the "zh" _j_ in Taj Mahal and Jacques, and the "y" _j_ in Jarlsberg.

Comment: Yes, but most of those are foreign words, the only one which can be considered truly English is "Jack". Even "Jacob" is a biblical name derived from Ancient Hebrew via Greek and Latin.