# Why did the /ʌ/ or /ʊ/ vowel in the Latin fundāre become the /aʊ/ of foundation?

Tags: etymology, orthography, latin

**Foundation** has its origins in the Latin:

OED

> fundātiōn-em. < Latin fundātiōn-em, noun of action < fundāre

Comment: Did **found** come from the Latin through the French *fonder*? As shown by the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/found#etymonline_v_11839).

Comment: Probably just one of those curious accidents of history. I assume it shares history with "fund", but that didn't get the vowel shift.

Comment: English spelling is not Latin spelling. And there is no /o/ in /faun'deʃən/.

Comment: A [meta-question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15686/) has been raised about the closing of this question.

Comment: @Greybeard What makes you think the vowel in the first syllable of Latin "fundāre" was /ʌ/? As far as I know, it was something close to /ʊ/.

Comment: @FlatAssembler - basically, the way I would pronounce it, but I have further edited the title. I think one must admit that, given the size and composition of the Roman Empire, there was probably little agreement on vowel sounds.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is probably there by influence from the verb *found*, as in "they founded a foundation." The diphthong [aʊ] developed regularly in English from the Middle English long vowel [uː], which was used pretty often in words borrowed from French, especially in stressed syllables.

*Foundation* and *found* ultimately come from the Latin verb *fundō, fundāre*. The verb *found* was taken into Middle English (first attested around 1290 per the OED) from Anglo-Norman French.

In the forms where it was stressed on the first syllable, the first part of this verb developed as follows:

- Latin [fund] (e.g. in *fundat*)
- Proto-Western-Romance: *[fond]
- Anglo-Norman French: [fũd] or [fũːd] (e.g. in [funde](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/funder#Old_French))
- Middle English: [fuːnd] (maybe also [fund] and [fond] as variants)

In Anglo-Norman French, the word had a nasal vowel ũ, which was probably long (as nasal vowels tend to be in modern French), so it would make sense for Middle English speakers to adopt the word with a long vowel. Compare *count, mount, fount, round, pronounce* and many other English words spelled with "oun" that were taken from Anglo-Norman French.<sup>1</sup>

The digraph "ou" (not just in this word, but in general) comes from Anglo-Norman French, where it was used, in variation with "o" and "u", to represent the vowel [u]. That is, in Anglo-Norman French, any of the spellings "fund", "fonde", "founde" might be used, with no difference in meaning or pronunciation. Per the Oxford English Dictionary, spellings starting with "fund" and "fond" also were used for some time in Middle English.

But English writers eventually came to use "ou" (and the variant "[ow](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/why-does-ow-have-two-different-sounds/265717#265717)") specifically as a means of representing the long vowel [uː] as opposed to the short vowel [u] spelled "u". It seems the in the case of "found", the pronunciation with [uː]—and corresponding spelling with "ou"—ended up as the standard form.

Middle English long [uː] developed into the modern English diphthong [aʊ], which we have continued to spell with the digraphs "ou" and "ow".

---

<sup>1</sup> I've discussed Anglo-Norman ũ in a few previous answers: [Why is the spelling of "company" different from the pronunciation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/440908/77227), [Why do "bomb" and "tomb" have different pronunciations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/322076/77227), [Why is "country" not pronounced like "count-tree"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/402621/77227)

Comment: Took me a minute to realize that when you said it shares etymology with "found" you weren't talking about the past participle of "find".

Comment: @Barmar You foundered on the difference between 'found' and 'found'.

Answer (score 4):

The verb *found* as in “build or establish the basis for “ is, [per Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/found)
“[from] Middle English *founden*, borrowed from Anglo-French *fonder*, *funder*, going back to Latin *fundāre*, derivative of *fundus* ‘bottom, base, foundation’.”

Meanwhile, *foundation* is “[from] Middle English *fundacioun*, borrowed from Anglo-French & Latin.” So likely the route to Modern English *foundation* —and the spelling that includes the **o** —was influenced by *founden* and/or *found*.

Answer (score 0):

The etymology of "foundation" as given by *The Shorter Oxford English Dictionary*

> [(O)Fr. *fondation* f. L. *fundatio(n-)* f. *fundat* pa. ppl stem of *fundare*: see FOUND *v*<sup>1</sup>, -ATION.]

The o from French has been combined with the u from Latin.