Why is bowl spelled with ⟨ow⟩?
Generally speaking, in cases where an Old English ⟨ā⟩ or ⟨o⟩ becomes /oʊ/ in Modern English, the result may be written with either ⟨oa⟩ or ⟨o…e⟩:

rād > road, grānian > groan
col > coal, fola > foal
— vs. —
stān > stone, rāp > rope
nosu > nose, smoca > smoke

The choice of which word ended up with which variant is seemingly arbitrary, according to this previous answer.
However, English bowl that corresponds to Old English bolla is written with ow. Why is bowl spelled with ⟨ow⟩?

Your first stop for this sort of question should be the OED, which says "The normal modern spelling would be boll n.1 which came down to 17th cent. in sense of ‘round vessel’, and is still used in sense of ‘round seed-vessel’; but the early Middle English pronunciation of ‑ōll as ‑ōwl (compare roll, poll, toll, etc.), has left its effects in the modern spelling bowl in the sense of ‘vessel’, which is thus at once separated in form from other senses of its own (see boll n.1), and confounded with bowl n.2 a ball, < French boule."

@StuartF Not everyone has a paid a subscription fee  or has free access to the OED via library membership.

@StuartF That's an answer, not a comment. The needful calls out to you.

Related: Why does "ow" have two different sounds - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/why-does-ow-have-two-different-sounds
