# Why are there 3 different ways to pronounce "oo"?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

My German colleagues were laughing at the way I pronounce *google*, and it led to a discussion.

- With words like *google*, *yahoo*, *poodle* and *loose*, the *oo* has a sound similar to the German *ü* sound.
- With words like *good* and *book*, it is more similar to how Germans pronounce a *oo* sound.
- For words like *door* we are not sure if that is the same or different.

The Germans want to know what the pronunciation rules are so they can improve their English. I am guessing that there are no rules, and the pronunciation possibly comes from the original language that the word comes from.

Are there any rules? Is there any reason why there are two different pronunciations? Can non-native speakers work out the correct pronunciation by looking at the other letters in the word or the etymology?

Comment: Don't forget about words like "Cooperate".

Comment: @Al Everett: Sometimes it's spelt "Co-operate".

Comment: @Al Everett: "cooperate" has been spelled either as FrustratedWithFormsDesigner says ("co-operate") or a diaeresis (dieresis on this side of the pond), ("coöperate"). Printers and publishers are dropping these diareses; one would be naïve to assume otherwise. So we will have to cooperate to pronounce "Food coop" and "Chicken coop" differently.

Comment: more than three: blood ʌ, brooch oʊ

Comment: It gets worse! Some particularly "lazy" speakers (myself included) don't really enunciate **fool** any different from **fall** :)

Comment: I was being a bit facetious.

Comment: If you think that's bad, try -ough: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31991/why-does-the-ending-ough-have-six-pronunciations

Comment: You could as easily ask "Why are there *only* 3 different..."

Comment: Google for "dearest creature in creation".

Comment: because its English and thats how we roll

Comment: In the hot questions list, I first assumed that this was a question about object oriented programming (often abbreviated OO).

Comment: So far we have *Google*, *noodle* [uː]; *book*, *took* [ʊ]; *door*, *floor* [oʊr/ɔː]; *cooperate*, *coop* [oʊ(w)ɒ / oʊ(w)ɔ]; *blood* [ʌ]; *brooch*, *Roosevelt* [oʊ]. Any others?

Comment: @Jon Purdy: How about _poor_ [ʊə]?

Comment: @Tragicomic: Sure. Though I say [uɚ] (to rhyme with *sure*, as it happens).

Comment: Yet another example of the illogicalness of english. I never expected other languages to pronounce google differently.

Comment: The oo sound in "google" is not like the German ü; it is rather like the u in German "gut", "Buch", etc.

Comment: Did somebody tell you English pronunciation is regular and logical and simple? They were not telling the truth.

Comment: I have developed 'The Hemovore's Dictum' to illustrate this discrepancy:  "Blood is good food."  But as I read your examples I realized that my Yankee pronunciation of *door, floor, et al.* is a *fourth* variety - and as far as I can tell, the only one of the four that overlaps with a "single-o" pronunciation (as in *for, nor, tor, et al.*)

Comment: . . . and then @sumelic ruined my day :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'd say that your German colleagues are mishearing the English pronunciations.

The German letter *ü* makes the sound [y], which does not occur in English.

The words *loose*, *poodle*, *food*, and most other words with *oo* have the vowel [u], which is usually spelled *u* or *uh* in German. Historically this is a long /o/ sound that was written with "oo", the pronunciation of which has shifted to [u] as a result of the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift).

Some words with *oo* have instead the vowel [ʊ]: *good*, *hood*, *book*. There is no rule that predicts which words have this pronunciation, so you have to memorize it. The [ʊ] sound occurs in German as an allophone of /u/ in closed syllables. The vowel [ʊ] is shorter, more lax, and slightly centralized relative to [u]. This sound also tends to come from an older long /o/, though the reasons for this split are complicated and obscure.

A very small number of words with *oo* are pronounced with an [o] vowel: *door*, *floor*. These words always end in *r*, because the final *r* colors the preceding vowel. This is the same sound that is spelled *o* or *oh* in German.

Comment: Better with proper phonetics :-)

Comment: Good answer. Give them Germans *das Boot* to the head.

Comment: We do have [ʊ] in German: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:IPA_for_German

Comment: Macmillan says "door" is pronounced /dɔː(r)/.

Comment: @starblue, the difference between [o] and [ɔ] is not significant in English, and dialects vary on which vowel they use for that phoneme.

Comment: This is a very nice answer.  I wonder if it's worth mentioning also that there are regional differences for some of the words.  Where I live, *roof* usually has the same vowel sound as in *food*, but in some places *roof* shares the vowel sound with *book*.

Comment: It's a good answer, but does not go into the "why", which was the stated question.

Comment: @Keith, I added some notes on the history of the sound which should clarify.

Comment: The word "poor" is not German; it comes from the Old French "poure" having identical meaning, which in French evolved into "pauvre". It has an [o] pronunciation for much the same reason "moor" does in A.E.; a relaxation of "ooh" into "oh" in most regional American dialects.

Comment: Please add and elucidate *blood*.

Answer (score 15):

### Phonetics of the "oo" sounds

I think there are 6 pronunciations of "oo" as a digraph. As other people have mentioned, it can also represent two vowels in hiatus, as in "cooperate" or "zoology".

#### 1. "OO" as in "GOOSE": traditionally /uː/, phonetically [ʉw]

> - With words like *google*, *yahoo*, *poodle* and *loose*, the *oo* has a sound similar to the German *ü* sound.

Although other people have said this is wrong, it actually isn't. The sound of English *oo* in many accents does resemble the sound of German *ü.* The conventional transcription of the English sound is /uː/, which happens to be different from the conventional transcription of the German "üh" sound (IPA /yː/) and the same as the conventional transcription of the German "uh" sound. However, **this does not mean that English "oo" and German "uh" actually sound exactly the same.** The International Phonetic Alphabet is a single "standard" in the sense that there is a single inventory of symbols and a single officially defined "cardinal" value given to each of these symbols. However, there is no single way these symbols are used in practice to transcribe words in particular languages. Unfortunately, it's necessary to make various language-specific simplifications and approximations; in addition, conservatism means that the phonetic symbols used to transcribe English often reflect older forms of the language and don't take into account recent sound changes.

You can find a general overview of the vowel sounds of contemporary British English on Geoff Lindsey's blog: [The British English vowel system](http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/british-vowels/).

Lindsey says

> I consider ɵw and ʉw equally acceptable transcriptions of SSB GOOSE.
>
> Certainly the widespread transcriptions ʊ and uː are fossils as far as
>   contemporary SSB is concerned (though the ʊ of *kaputt* of course
>   survives in the north of England and in Australia). I commend those
>   Germans (and others) who trust their ears more than their
>   dictionaries, and use their *ü* rather than their *u* when speaking
>   English.

A small detail that Lindsey mentions in a [later blog post](http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/goose-backing/): in one particular context, before the sound /l/ when it ends a syllable, as in words like *fool*, it is in fact common for speakers to use a further-back value that is closer to German "uh" than German "üh."

Lindsey covers (a variety of) British English; you can additionally see maps showing the fronting of traditional /uː/ in American English in the *[Atlas of North American English](http://www.atlas.mouton-content.com/secure/generalmodules/anae/unit0034/genunstart.html)*: [the fronting of /uw/ after coronals](http://www.atlas.mouton-content.com/secure/generalmodules/anae/maps/map_12_1.html), [after non-coronals](http://www.atlas.mouton-content.com/secure/generalmodules/anae/maps/map_12_2.html).

#### 2. "OO" as in "FOOT": traditionally /ʊ/, phonetically [ɵ]

> - With words like *good* and *book*, it is more similar to how Germans pronounce a *oo* sound.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. As far as I know, in German spelling, "oo" represents a long vowel /oː/. This is not very similar at all to the sound in English "good." Conventionally, the vowel in "good" is transcribed as /ʊ/, which happens to be the same symbol used to represent the short vowel in the first syllable of German "Butter." However, the actual phonetic value of the vowel in "good" is, according to Lindsey, best transcribed as [ɵ], a central vowel. He compares it to the "French schwa" in words like *le*; the closest equivalent in German would probably be the "short ö" sound found in e.g. *Göttin.*

#### 3. "OOR" as in "DOOR": like "ore" as in "more" ([oː] or [o˞])

> - For words like *door* we are not sure if that is the same or different.

The British English pronunciation of the word "door" is conventionally transcribed /dɔː/. Lindsey says the /ɔː/ would be better represented phonetically with [oː]. In other words, a good approximation is the German "long o" sound in a word like *Mond.*

In American English, there is the consonant "r" at the end, which has no good equivalent sound in German: /dɔːr/. (In fact, the "r" sound is more likely to be realized non-consonantally as "r-coloring" on the vowel: [ɔ˞] or [o˞], but this would be even harder I think for a German speaker.)

It's common for "oo" to make the sound /ɔː/ (that is, [oː], German "oh") before the letter "r."

#### 4. "OOR" as in "POOR" can optionally have the vowel of "tour"

Some speakers use a distinct sound for "oor" in a few words, such as *poor* and *moor.* This sound is traditionally transcribed /ʊə/ in British English, and /ʊr/ in American English. It's commonly replaced with the sound of "more" in both regions, so it's really not necessary to learn it. If you do, the British pronunciation is somewhat similar to the sound in German "nur". This sound is more commonly heard after /j/, in words spelled with "ure": Lindsey transcribes it as /ʉwə/ or /ɵː/.

#### 5. "OOD" in "BLOOD" and "FLOOD" only: like "mud"

As user46928 mentions, there is another pronunciation of *oo* that only occurs in two words: *blood*, *flood.*  The vowel here is conventionally transcribed /ʌ/, although phonetically it's often closer to [ɐ]; there isn't a great equivalent in German, but it's probably closest to German "short a", or to the sound of unstressed *-er* as in *Sommer* (not the sound of stressed *-er* as in *werten*). It's sometimes written /ə/: it's not like German /ə/, although it may be similar to English /ə/.

#### 6. "OO" in "BROOCH" only: like "coach"

This is very marginal, but as Theta30 mentioned in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36905/why-are-there-3-different-ways-to-pronounce-oo#comment67257_36905), the word "brooch" is pronounced /broʊtʃ/ (or in British English, /brəʊtʃ/), the same as "broach" (in fact, both words have the same etymological origin according to the Oxford English Dictionary).

### Etymology and distribution of the "oo" sounds

(Despite what I said in the phonetics section, I'll resort to the traditional but phonetically inaccurate symbols /uː/, /ʊ/, /ʌ/ in this section because it's easier to discuss historical development with these symbols.)

The usual pronunciation is "long", as in "goose"; the "short" vowel sound of "foot" is actually pretty rare. The short pronunciation can generally be seen as conditioned by some kind of "shortening environment". Wikipedia gives somewhat of an overview: [Shortening of /uː/ to /ʊ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_back_vowels#Shortening_of_.2Fu.CB.90.2F_to_.2F.CA.8A.2F), although I would take it with a very large grain of salt because it seems to be edited by amateurs, like me, rather than real experts. (The article gives two contradictory accounts of the development of the vowel in "wool", for example.) And since I am a self-admitted amateur, you should also take this following section with a grain of salt (but if you find an error, I'd appreciate a comment or edit!).

I'll use "Early Modern English" here to refer to English right after the Great Vowel Shift; "Middle English" (abbreviated "MidE") is pre-Great Vowel Shift, and "Old English" (abbreviated "OE") is pre-Norman Conquest. The "OED" is the "Oxford English Dictionary".

General background information you should know:

- Both "oo" sounds generally come from the same source, Early Modern English /uː/. The /ʊ/ sound is the result of a shortening process that was only partially predictable and that seems to have been active both before and after another vowel change that un-rounded /ʊ/ to /ʌ/ in most environments. Some dialects in Northern English lack the /ʊ/ to /ʌ/ change entirely, and therefore lack the sound /ʌ/.
- Early Modern English /uː/ generally developed via the Great Vowel Shift from Middle English /oː/, which in turn mostly came from Old English /oː/, which is represented in modern scholarly transcriptions as "ō". This o-sound is the origin of the spelling ⟨oo⟩.
- Middle English /uː/ (usually spelled "ou" or "ow") mostly turned into the Early Modern English diphthong /aʊ/ via the Great Vowel Shift. However, before a labial consonant such as /p/ /f/ /v/ /m/, this change was inhibited, and Middle English /uː/ became Early Modern English /uː/, merging with the reflex of /oː/. This led to some un-etymological spellings such as "room" < MidE "roum(e)", "rowm(e)" < OE *rūm* and "droop" < MidE "droupe", "drowp(e)" Old Norse *drúpa.*
- Another spelling quirk is that some words that were likely pronounced with /uːv/ or /uv/ in Early Modern English were spelled with "ov", with a single "o": examples are "behove" < OE *bi-/behōfian* (now commonly spelled "behoove" in the United States) and "love" < OE *lufu* (which probably usually had /uv/, but dialectally or poetically could have /uːv/), as well as the non-native verbs "move" and "prove" which have somewhat unclear phonetic development to modern /uːv/.

As fas as I can tell, short "oo" is possible before /k d t f m/, and after /w/. Here is an overview of these shortening environments.

#### Before the voiceless velar plosive /k/: short is regular.

**-ook.** Early Modern English /uːk/ seems to have quite regularly been shortened to /ʊk/, and consistently after the sound change of /ʊ/ to /ʌ/. (Speaking here of the pronunciations that contributed to modern standard English; it is well known that there is regional variability, and some regions apparently don't show shortening in "-ook" words.) So there are very few exceptions to the ⟨ook⟩-/ʊk/ correspondence in modern standard English, and they all seem to be words that originated at a time period after shortening was active.

/uːk/ occurs exceptionally in the following words:

- *spook*: < Dutch *spook*
- *kook*: unclear etymology; possibly from *cuckoo* (which has a variable first vowel)
- *mook*: unclear etymology. Apparently short for some speakers.
- *snooker*: unclear etymology. Short for some speakers.

Etymology of words with regular pronunciation:

/ʊk/ from OE *-ōc* /oːk/:

- *book, brook* (n), *cook, hook, rook* (the bird), *shook, took, look*

/ʊk/ from other sources:

- *brook* (v): < OE *-ūk*. The lack of diphthongization to /aʊ/ between Middle English and Early Modern English is apparently irregular, but it may be significant that no native English word today contains /aʊk/: the word *suck* < OE *sūcan* shows a different irregular development (early shortening of the vowel), and the word “[louk](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/louk)” < OE *lūcan* is now obsolete or dialectal.
- *crook*: The OED says < "Middle English *crōk, crōc,* apparently < Old Norse *krókr*"
- *rook* (chess piece): The OED says "< Anglo-Norman and Middle French *roc*", 
  ultimately "< Arabic *ruḵḵ*"
- *rookie*: uncertain etymology
- *cookie*: The OED says “probably < Dutch *koekje* /ˈkuːkjə/ diminutive of *koek* 'cake'," 
  I think its pronunciation has possibly been influenced by English "cook"

#### Before the coronal plosives (t d): several possibilities.

**-ood.** Early Modern English /uːd/ seems to have only sometimes been shortened to /ʊd/; this is perhaps comparable to the inconsistent shortening of *-ead* from Middle English /ɛːd/ (as in *bead, thread*). This shortening seems to have occured before the /ʊ/ > /ʌ/ change in a couple of words. “Wood” is a special case that actually maybe never had a long vowel (I don’t actually know); see section on “woo-” below.

- /uːd/ < OE *-ōd* /oːd/: *brood, food, mood* (emotional), *rood, snood*
- /ʊd/ < OE *-ōd* /oːd/: *good, stood, hood*

     < OE *-ād* /ɑːd/: *-hood* (irregular vowel development between OE and MidE)

     < OE *-ud* /ud/: *wood*; see section on “woo-” below.
- /ʌd/ < OE *-ōd*: *flood, blood* (apparently shortened before /ʊ/ > /ʌ/ change)

**-oot.** Shortening is variable and apparently fairly recent in at least some cases. (There's some dialectal variation today for *root.*) Perhaps comparable to the inconsistent shortening of *-eat* from Middle English /ɛːt/ (as in *meat, sweat*).

- /ʊt/: *soot, foot* only
- /uːt/: *shoot, boot*, many others
- variable /uːt/ or /ʊt/: *root*

#### Before the labial non-plosive consonants (f m): sometimes variable.

**-oof.** Early Modern English /uːf/ seems to have only shortened to /ʊf/ variably and fairly recently. This is perhaps comparable to the inconsistent shortening of *-eaf* from Middle English /ɛːf/ (as in *leaf, deaf*). It’s also interesting to compare this to the early shortening of Early Modern English /uːv/ > /uv/ > /ʊv/ > /⁠ʌv/ that apparently occured in the words *glove* (< OE *glóf*), *dove* (n) (< Germanic **dūƀōn* or Old Norse *dūfa*), and *shove* (< OE *sc(e)úfan*).

- variable /uːf/ or /ʊf/ < OE *-ōf*: *roof, hoof* 

            < OE *ōwef*: *woof* (weaving) (unusual phonetic development)
- /ʊf/: *woof* (dog bark) (onomatopoeia; no OE etymon)

**-oom.** There also seems to be some current variability in the reflex of Early Modern English /uːm/, from Old English /oːm/ or /uːm/:

- /uːm/: *gloom, doom*
- variable /uːm/ or /ʊm/: *room, groom, broom*

#### After the labial semivowel /w/: sometimes short, kind of.

**woo-.** This isn’t a useful class of words to memorize, but they’re interesting in terms of etymology. The sequence ⟨wu⟩ is uncommon in English spelling (the letter w, as its name implies, used to be written as two u’s, which makes “wu” the awkward sequence ⟨uuu⟩). Consider the spelling of the word “wolf” /wʊlf/ < OE *wulf.*  This tendency to avoid “wu” seems to have led to the predominance of the spellings “wool” (< Old English *wull*) and “wood” (< Old English *widu, wiodu,* later *wudu*) over “wull” and “wud”. Phonetically, the preceding semivowel /w/ seems to have preserved the rounding on the vowel, inhibiting the general Early Modern English change of /ʊ/ to /ʌ/. As far as I can tell, "woof" is unrelated.

I would guess that all speakers use /ʊ/ in these two words; if there are any speakers that use /uː/, that would require some more explanation. It is known that at least some dialects had lengthening of Old English /u/ to Middle English /oː/ in open syllables: this is supposed to be the origin of the Early Modern English pronunciations of *above* < OE *abufan* and *love* < OE *lufu* with long /uː/ that show up from time to time in poetry. (See "[Rhyme in Elizabethan sonnets](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73645)".) This could at least explain */wu:d/, if that pronunciation exists. I have no idea how */wu:l/ could be explained, if it exists.

Other words containing “woo” (aside from "woof") have long “oo”, such as “woo”, “swoon” and “swoop”. These words tend to have unusual etymologies, often with irregular development from Old English (if they even go back that far).

#### Before the liquid /r/

Discussed above in the phonetics section.

#### In all other environments

As said earlier, "oo" is generally long in all other environments.

### Sources

Example words taken from [Jakub Marian’s useful article on the pronunciation of “oo”](https://jakubmarian.com/pronunciation-of-oo-in-english-long-or-short/), which [Josh](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/66974/josh) linked to in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368598/why-is-there-discrepancy-between-the-pronunciation-of-words-ending-with-ook#comment861239_368598) on a related question, as well as [OneLook Dictionary Seach](http://www.onelook.com). OneLook and its indexed dictionaries were used along with the Oxford English Dictionary to find etymological information.

Information on the Great Vowel shift taken in part from this great ["Great Vowel Shift" handout](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~kroch/courses/lx310/handouts/handouts-09/ringe/gvs-revised.pdf) from [Anthony Kroch's website](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~kroch/), which I also learned about from Josh's answer to the following question: [Why do "bomb" and "tomb" have different pronunciations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320512/why-do-bomb-and-tomb-have-different-pronunciations/320515#320515)

Comment: I'd say unstressed _-er_ /ɐ/ in German is a much better match for /ʌ/ than _a_ is: in a word like _Sommer_ [ˡzɔmɐ], both vowels are reasonably close to (British) English /ʌ/, the latter more so than the former.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I assumed it would be difficult for a German to use that "er" sound in a stressed syllable, and I don't want to accidentally suggest /ɛə/.

Comment: This is an excellent answer covering current British pronunciations.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I'd say that in "google" or "yahoo", "oo" sounds more like the German "u" rather than "ü". There's no "ü" sound in English really -- that I can think of.

The difference between "google" and "book" is more that "book" is a very short "oo" sound (so a German "u", but very short) whereas "google" and "yahoo" are long "oo" sounds. "door" is entirely different, in that it is pronounced more like the "o" in "Dortmund".

I'd say the general rule is that "oo" is a long sound, and "book" and "door" are exceptions to the rule.

Another exception is the word "good", which also has a short sound like in "put", "could" and "should".

Like @Al suggested in his comment, there's also "cooperate", which is pronounced like "co-operate", as if the two "o"s where distinct.

Comment: Like "Dortmund" with a light Westphalian accent. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There are actually FOUR (y'all are forgetting *blood*, *flood*).  The reason for this last one is timing (relative chronology):  in the pronunciation of some words containing  that vowel ( /u:/) had shortened and merged with /ʊ/ in time for the next change taking any [ʊ] to [ʌ] to apply.

Answer (score -2):

Relating to the "why" part of the question, the answer is very complicated and there is no compact set of answers, therefore there are no hard and fast rules.

The words that have what we call the "short oo", such as "book", "hook", etc. originally came from either the German un-dotted "u" ("buch"), which has a similar pronunciation somewhere in the area of the way we pronounce "pull", or from "o" ("hoken") and a little extra influence, possibly through feedback via the Dutch branch of the Germanic family ("hoek").

Words with the long "oo" as in "pool" and "cool" are evenly split between German "u" (these words would have originally had a "short oo" but evolved with time and dialect), German "uh" (which usually has the "ooh" pronunciation), and French "ou" (again nearly identical to a "long oo"; "pool" came from "*poule*", and "poor" was originally the Old French "*poure*" which in the French language was further influenced by Latin to become the modern "*pauvre*").

Words with the "oh" sound were either influenced by the "Great Vowel Shift", or have become more relaxed in pronunciation with the rise of American regional dialects. Most Americans would pronounce "poor" and "moor" the way most B.E. speakers would pronounce "pore" and "more". Words like "door" were influenced towards [o] very early in their life as the proto-Germanic "*dur*" and Old French "*porte*" met in Saxony and Briton to form the old English "*dor*".

Comment: This description has a lot of inaccuracies. English is not derived from either modern German, or modern Dutch, or any combination of the two. The pronunciation of "poor" and "moor" with an o-like vowel is not due to the Great Vowel Shift. I highly doubt the pronunciation of "door" was influenced at all by that of French "porte."