# Why is there discrepancy between the pronunciation of words ending with "-ook"?

Tags: pronunciation

There are a significant number of words in the English language that end with "-ook".  Most of them (e.g. book, cook, hook, look, nook, rook, took) are pronounced with "o͝ok"; however, spook, mook, and kook are pronounced as "o͞ok".  Is there a non-obvious rule that is at play here?  Why is there a discrepancy?

Edit: This not a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36905/why-are-there-3-different-ways-to-pronounce-oo) as was suggested by @Josh: that was a question on HOW to pronounce "oo" words (by ELLs), not WHY they are pronounced this way.

Comment: Have you looked up their etymologies?

Comment: Why would you expect consistency in English pronunciation?

Comment: The words in your first list are mostly from Old English, *spook* is from Dutch, and *mook* and *kook* are 20th-century words.

Comment: @Josh This is not a duplicate of that question: that was a question on HOW to pronounce "oo" words (by ELLs), not WHY they are pronounced this way.

Comment: @Barmar this seems like it should be an official answer

Comment: My cat's name is ***Toots*** (short "oo" as in ***wood**, Tootsie roll, Toots & the Maytals*). I'm surprised how often people ask her name then repeat it back with a long "oo" (as in ***wooed**, food, Tooting Bec*), as if they don't hear the difference.

Comment: Presumably you mean /u/ versus /ʊ/ using standard phonetic notation.

Comment: ***Pronunciation of ‘oo’ in English – long or short?** https://jakubmarian.com/pronunciation-of-oo-in-english-long-or-short/

Comment: **Lax** high back /ʊ/ is the normal pronunciation of OO before K in English. In some borrowed or recent words, however, **tense** high back /u/ occurs instead. [American English phonemic symbols here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf).

Comment: Sorry that your question got closed. I also think it would be nice to have separate questions to address separate issues related to these sounds; however, since I can't make a post here, I've edited [my answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/353966/77227) to the linked question to add a section on the etymological origin and current distribution of these sounds.

Comment: Thanks, @sumelic.  It did appear like they were two different questions; however, I think that your amendment is a good idea!