# Rules for pronouncing the “gh” sound

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology

In English, we have many words ending in or containing “gh”, but in some cases, the two letters are silent, while in others, it is pronounced as “f” . We have the words *tough*, *rough*, and *draught*, which pronounce "gh" as an "f" sound, while the words *height*, *weight*, *through*, *drought*, and many others do not pronounce the sound at all.

Are there any rules governing the pronunciations of these words? Or is the reason for this based in the origins of the words?

Edit: My question focuses specifically on the “gh” combination, not the pronunciation of “ough”. In my examples I gave words such as the words *height* and *weight* which contain “eigh”, not just words with “ough”.

Comment: Yes, origins are a good guide for this one.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is a rule, as there are relatively recent local pronunciations in England where most "gh" combinations are said as "ff" (e.g. 'siff' for 'sigh'). There's also the places Keighley (keethley) and Lough Neagh (loch nay) to contend with.

Comment: @Phil: in what region is sigh pronounced as siff?

Comment: @PhilMJones why do you think "siff" for "sigh" is recent?

Comment: 'f' isn't the only way gh is pronounced. Not that you can consider it or any combination of letters to necessarily be the thing that "has" some sound that is part of the sound of a word or phrase.

Comment: @phoog Ah, what I meant was that it had continued until relatively recently. Apologies for lack of clarity.  See my answer on this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525773/u-k-regional-anomaly-in-pronouncing-ought

Comment: Reminds me of the joke where, if you use pronunciations of letter combinations taken from certain words, then you can claim that "ghoti" should be pronounced [fish]

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/594992/2085).

Answer (score 14):

The question as posed has no answer, because it starts from an incorrect assumption.
Modern English **has** no "gh" sound. Middle English had one, [but it was lost](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/148033/15299).

What that means is that the sounds changed, but the spelling didn't, since the spelling got fixed before the Early Modern English period (roughly, 1600-1800; after 1800 is Modern English). When a big sound change is happening, different things happen in different dialects, and then they all merge together, with different words coming from different dialects that made different changes.

While the [x] allophone of the ME /h/ phoneme (which was spelled "gh" in ME) was being lost, people started hearing [x] as a different voiceless fricative (like /f/ or /θ/ -- there are dialects of English still where *trough* is pronounced like *troth* instead of *troff*), or else they just stopped hearing it at all, so it was gone in the next generation's speech. But the spelling remained, to encourage people to question it.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @user888379 it's interesting, but it stops short of actually providing a useful answer.

Comment: Feel free to make on up yourself, then. What **are** the rules for pronouncing the gh sound?

Comment: @JohnLawler We're just [ghoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti) for some sort of guideline!

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- You'll be waiting a long time. Look at the name of the English town Loughborough (which is pronounced "Luffburrow"). If you can work out a rule which will tell you how to pronounce that you're doing better than I can.

Comment: @BoldBen My comment was primarily a joke, though bizarrely enough, my first guess of pronunciation of Loughbourough was "Loffburrow".

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- We can guess that because we already know *borough* is read "burrow", but figuring out a rule that can predict *rough* is read as /f/ while *borough* is silent will be a challenge indeed.

Comment: "borough" isn't read as "burrow", it's read as "bruh", only one syllable and with a reduced vowel. This is pretty common across British toponyms (and one reason why Americans stand out a lot when talking about the capital of Scotland)

Comment: @BoldBen As Tristan says, the locals pronounce it "Lufbra".  In fact, many organisations in the town (including at the University) use that spelling as a nickname.  (It's similar "Borough" on its own, as an administrative district, which would be "burrah" in most of the UK, not "Burrow" as it would in the USA)

Comment: @Chronocidal Burrah is possibly a better representation of the sound, however I have a predominently Derbyshire accent and so I tend to pronounce "burrow" as people with RP and many other accents would pronounce "burrah". It's a bit like the RP and southern representation of "up north" as "oop north" and the northern representation of "down south" as "dayn sayth" or "dahn sarf". The people with the northern, 'posh' and estuary accents spell the words normally and find the representations of their own pronunciations odd. This only strengthens my point about the pronunciation of 'gh' though.

Comment: @lambshaanxy dunno call it *rag* or *coarse cloth* (or bombclat). Live is rough these days, we can be so happy. It may be difficult to believe that's where *great* is from (*grit*) but it is. Actually German *grob* "rough" has a cognate in English *gruff*, how about that, and probably not from *gh* (given they could mostly not write). More over, English has lost hundreds of g- in words like *enough*, *yearn*, *yawn*. So, ya had *a'ruff* day?