# How is "cyan" pronounced and where is the stress?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english

How is the word 'cyan' pronounced? Is it pronounced *sigh-yann* /saɪæn/ or *sigh-yun* /saɪən/ and is the stress on the first or second syllable?

The online dictionary entries indexed by [OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=cyan&ls=a) list both "SIGH-ann" /ˈsaɪæn/ and "SIGH-un" /ˈsaɪən/, with the stress on the first syllable.  Some of them show secondary stress on the second syllable (/ˈsaɪˌæn/), such as [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/cyan) and the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cyan) (which transcribes it as "⁠sī**⁠′⁠**⁠ăn⁠′⁠" with a larger stress mark after the first syllable), but none of them lists any pronunciation variants with the primary stress on the second syllable.

However, there are allusions to pronunciations with primary stress on the second syllable in various other places on the web:

[Syllabification of "Cyan", using spaces (space bar) to separate syllables?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20160504150528AAsNxAF) (Yahoo Answers):

> Cy AN. Stress is on the second syllable. 
> Cara

[CYANIST - MYSTcommunity](http://www.mystcommunity.com/board/index.php?/topic/4222-cyanist/):

> Although, is it true that Cyan, when properly pronounced, rhymes with
>   Diane?  ;) Because I'm terribly attached to it rhyming with "lion,"
>   even more than I was attached to "D'ni" having its second syllable
>   stressed, which was before I learned it was supposed to have its first
>   syllable stressed, which was before RAWA dropped the bomb that, in
>   fact, the second syllable IS supposed to get more emphasis than the
>   first. (75th Trombone, Posted 11 March 2003 - 07:28 AM)

[Behind the Name: User Comments for the Name Cyan](http://www.behindthename.com/name/cyan/comments)

> In Britain at least, the word "cyan" is pronounced "sie-ANNE", with
>   the stress on the 2nd syllable not the 1st. 
> -- Anonymous User 
>   3/7/2006

Does anyone have any more information about the different pronunciations of this word?

Comment: "Sie-ANNE" is how it's pronounced in General American.

Comment: @54696D - what is General American?

Comment: @Josh61 It's what you hear on TV.

Comment: Related: [How to pronounce “halcyon”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/how-to-pronounce-halcyon)

Comment: I'm nearly 56 yo and I've always pronounced it as ky-ann... Didn't realize this was wrong till my 12yo granddaughter corrected me and I googled it... Grandma is now sitting with egg on her face lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Oxford Dictionary Online specifies the pronunciation of **cyan** as /ˈsīən/. With this pronunciation, the first syllable carries the stress.

Merriam Webster's online dictionary, on the other hand, specifies two valid pronunciations of **cyan**: /ˈsī-ˌan, -ən/. The dictionary entry in this case puts the stress on the first syllable for both pronunciations.

Having spent a good deal of time in both the UK and the USA, my experience with the word supports Merriam Webster's entry, but not fully. I've heard both pronunciations (/ˈsī-ˌan, -ən/) in colloquial *and* professional use, and I've seen the word **cyan** appear in poetry and spoken in certain dialects (especially Irish and Australian) such that the stress can be manipulated by syntactic structure. Your already-referenced dictionary discrepancies support this broad interpretation.

Ultimately, you're asking a very complicated linguistic question here, and there exists no narrow answer because a narrow answer necessarily depends on relegating the scope of the question to a specific dialectic region *and* even a specific usage example within that dialectic region.

Comment: /ī/ is not IPA. It is meaningless custom transcription to any international audience. The diphthong should be written as some variant of /ai/.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my personal contribution:

I am Australian, and I pronounce it sai-ANN, with the stress on the second syllable. I asked a few friends, and they all agreed that this pronunciation was correct.

I asked a Belgian friend, and they gave SAI-an as the pronunciation, with the stress on the first syllable.

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this sort of question yourself by googling for an online English dictionary that has a button you can click for pronunciation. Here is a link to [‘cyan’ in the Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cyan). (Not the way I would pronounce it, incidentally. I’d put the stress on the last syllable, but then I don’t work in the printing industry, so presumably I’m wrong.)

(You can purchase dictionaries for your smart phone that do this too. I use this with the Ultralingua series for foreign languages on my iPhone.)

**Addendum**

Just discovered that the [Cambridge dictionary on-line](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cyan?) has buttons for both British and American pronunciation. Of course, there is still the problem of regional variations or alternatives.

Comment: The difficulty is that the dictionaries are not consistent.

Comment: @Mitch — Yes. Two points I subsequently thought of adding. 1. Possible US v. British pronunciation. 2. Talking dictionary only gives one alternative. Useful for languages that tend to have very standard stress and pronunciation.