# Has "segway" become an acceptable substitute for "segue"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

For a long time, I used the word *segway* in relative contentment, as a useful word to mean "to transition to."  As in:

> We're getting off-topic.  Let's segway to the next discussion point, shall we?

Then one day, and to my surprise, I was shocked, after making a comment on somebody's blog, to be haughtily corrected and informed that correct usage was actually [*segue*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/segue), which apparently comes by the Italian *seguire*, meaning "to follow."  I was additionally told that *segway* was a vulgar imitation used by know-nothings, a sort of word like *bonafied* that instantly revealed one's class and relative ignorance.

Wow! I had little doubt that the use of *segway* was substatially bolstered by the hype and general pop-cultural awareness of Dean Kamen's [famous flop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segway_PT), but back then, I'd always thought he'd fittingly named his vehicle after the word itself, and it was strange to me to learn that the Segway  was in fact knowingly named after a corruption.

On the other hand, this is a mistake I continually hear lots of people, even educated people, make — cf. for example, whoever Joel is talking to at the 61<sup>st</sup> minute of [the latest podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/podcast-88/).

So has *segway* become acceptable as a replacement for *segue*? Can *segue* be considered all but dead? To be clear, as this is StackExchange, I'm not looking for, "ooh! I say it this way", and "no, I say it that way!" responses;  I'm looking more for quantitative data, usage by established authorities (is the NYRB using *segway*?), and perhaps discussions from those who have written on this before.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I had assumed from the heading that this question was about spelling. From reading the question, it seems that you are asking about pronunciation? Regardless of which spelling you select (segue for a transition, Segway for the product) I am only aware of one pronunciation. Incidentally, so is my dictionary...

Comment: The word "segue" is pronounced in essentially the same way as "segway" (at least, in the accents I'm familiar with).  For instance, in the linked podcast, there's no reason to think the speaker believes the word is spelled "segway".

Comment: @Henry: it's definitely not pronounced in the same way in Italian! (and it's exact translation would be *it follows* which does not really fit in those sentences).

Comment: @OP How exactly did you think "segue" was pronounced, that these "mistakes" you hear (like that podcast) aren't correct uses of the correct word? (@nico, it's an accepted english word though, how it's pronounced, or how its meaning is different, in Italian isn't all that relevant. English doesn't _have_ an /e/ vowel, and /ɡw/ is not a common cluster)

Comment: As @Henry etc. say, *segue* in English is pronounced like *segway*, as the closest approximation to the Italian pronunciation within the English phonetic stock.  This has already been discussed quite a bit in [an answer to another question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-words-are-commonly-mispronounced-by-literate-people-who-read-them-before-the/1439#1439).

Comment: The two words are homophones, both of which are pronounced **/ˈsɛgweɪ/**.

Comment: @tchrist, Wow, I've always pronounced it as "s.egg" "way".

Comment: @Pacerier: why did you think that's different from the pronunciation tchrist mentioned? I'm confused.

Comment: What has not been mentioned here is that music traditionally uses Italian terms and that segue is one of them, meaning that one complete, often contrasting piece, follows from another complete piece, without break. I had always thought that it was pronounced like league until just recently.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Google Ngram data provides a little insight although the introduction of the Segway was quite recent. There does seem to be a dip in the use of 'segue' since around 2003 which coincides somewhat with the rise of the Segway in the common consciousness.

[image: Google Books Ngram for 'segue' vs 'Segway']

Perhaps 'segue' is at a disadvantage owing to its not having what might be called an 'intuitive' spelling. Hence the more phonetically appealing 'segway', boosted by the invention and subsequent naming of the ridiculous personal transport vehicle, is making inroads.

(My personal opinion: the word is spelled 'segue' and always will be. Anything else is just laziness and poor literacy.)

Comment: "laziness and poor literacy" is one of the ways that language evolves. Don't fight it too hard, you'll go mad. :)

Comment: The peak in "Segway" from 1901 to 1908 is unexplained.

Comment: @JoeZeng: Look at the sample size. That is probably a very small number of citations. Also, the [Ngram has changed](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=segue%2Csegway&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=) since this answer was posted, likely because Google’s corpus has grown.

Comment: Sometimes, when I navigate a link, I forget that the post isn't as recent as the one I came from.

Comment: @JoeZeng: Same here. It’s also a bit of a problem how answers need to be maintained, especially if their sources have changed.

Comment: How is the use of "segway" a sign of illiteracy? Just wondering...

Comment: There's a significant extra reason why Segway suddently appears in NGram: it is the brand of an electric vehicle that was introduced ...well ... guess when? ;)  So the increase in usage showing in NGram is _not_ indicative of a sudden acceptance of substitution (though the dip might be taken that way?). The use of segway in place of segue is slight symptom of illiteracy in the same way that any spelling mistake is: a illiteracy being a measure of how poorly a person understands a language.   FWIW Segway is a proper noun, and should be capitalised :)

Comment: I found myself here after trying to write the word "sedgewayed" and realising I have no idea how it should be spelt.

Answer (score 23):

The only meaning of *segway* reported by the NOAD, and the OED, is the following:

> *Segway*: [trademark] a two-wheeled motorized personal vehicle consisting of a platform for the feet mounted above an axle and an upright post surmounted by handles.

As per the origin of the word, both the dictionaries say "an invented word based on *segue*."

I would say that *segway* is not an acceptable substitute for *segue*.

Comment: +1 The word is a trade name and may not be used in other senses, at least commercially.

Comment: @Kris There is no onus on people to stop using trade names as words. The onus is on the holder of the trademark to try to stop people using them generically and if they fail to do so they may lose their trademark. Random people using trademarks generically risk nothing though may be asked by the trademark holder to stop.

Answer (score 10):

http://www.english-for-students.com/Segway-or-Segue.html
This sums it up:

> When you shift to a new topic or activity, you segue.
>   Many people unfamiliar with the unusual Italian spelling of the word misspell it as “segway.”
>
> This error is being encouraged by the deliberately punning name used by the manufacturers of the Segway Human Transporter.

Comment: **This** should be the answer.

Comment: Note that in spelling "segue" as "Segway", you are inadvertently advertising for the company by disemminating their brand name.

Answer (score 4):

The OED does not list *segway*, it only lists *segue*, as musical slang.

> **segue**, *n. Mus. slang.*
>
> (ˈsɛgweɪ)
>
> [f. prec.]
>
> An uninterrupted transition from one song or melody to another. (Used of both live and pre-recorded music.)

As your commenter made a point of *segway* being *a vulgar imitation used by know-nothings*, you should then point him out that *segue* is not the correct Italian word for this concept. One should rather use *proseguimento* or *proseguire* (or many others, it really depends on the sentence). *Segue* means "it follows", therefore, you are saying:

> We're getting off-topic. Let's it follows to the next discussion point, shall we?

Which is meaningless.

Also the correct italian pronunciation is not ˈsɛgweɪ but rather se'gwe

Personally, I would just say:

> We're getting off-topic. Let's continue to the next discussion point, shall we?

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Just because "segue" comes from an Italian word meaning "it follows" doesn't mean every use of the English word derived from it should be replaced with "it follows".  Segue has become a perfectly good English word, with its own meaning and its own pronunciation.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, just saying that the comment about segway being a "vulgar imitation" makes no point at all, as the original word is not correct either strictly speaking. As it is often the case for Italian words that have entered common English usage and are often *tortured* into slightly different meanings (but slightly enough to sound very odd to any Italian speaker) :)

Comment: Except that its Italian roots are irrelevant to its correctness.  The original word *is* perfectly correct.

Comment: I disagree. *segue* is a verb, and is being used as a noun. Then, I'm not saying you shouldn't use it, just that if any Italian is around he will probably be quite perplexed by what you are trying to say. It's like people using "bravo" for women, personally I find it just hilarious: every time I hear it it sounds to me like "I'm complimenting you young woman, and telling you you're a man!".

Comment: You are still incorrect.  Segue is also a noun.  As for any nearby Italian speakers who might be entertained, given the vast number of words English has borrowed from other languages, I'm sure Italians are far from alone in that reaction.

Comment: Segue is only a verb in Italian. It is used as a noun in English. Sorry, but when I borrow words from other languages I try to use them coherently with the original language, if you don't like to do so, nothing wrong with it, I am just pointing out that you're using a verb as a noun, that's all. Not saying it's inherently wrong.

Comment: @nico: No, using segue as a noun is not "using a verb as a noun", it's using an English noun as an English noun.  The English word segue *is not* the Italian word segue, it's a different word that happens to be historically related.

Comment: @nico Perhaps we should stop saying "deja vu", borrowed from the French?

Comment: @Geoff Having lived long enough abroad I have now changed my opinion on this. I still maintain that it is grammatically incorrect and I do not use it, but I am not bothered anymore by people using it :)

Comment: @nico Until the day I posted my comment above, I'd always thought that segue was pronounced like league and that Americans created Segway, only to find out that segue is pronounced segway.

Answer (score 1):

The question is hard to answer because the framing is unclear. A podcast (audio only) is referenced, but elsewhere it looks like the question is between the spelling "segway" and "segue". The only resolution for this contradiction is if the author believed that "segway" and "segue" are pronounced differently. Dictionaries would indicate that they are homophones. So perhaps an alternate pronunciation for "segue" is at play. I've heard my mother pronounce "segue" as "seeg". Whether that's a regional variant, a personal quirk, or a common error, I'm not sure, though she did study music so perhaps it was taught. Perhaps that's where the confusion lies.

Comment: I've always thought that segue was pronounced like league until now.

Answer (score -3):

*Segway*, *seque*, or *segue*.

Ameriglish is an evolving language; in the last two years since this thread began, *segway* is gaining ground over *segue*, as vulgar an incorrect as some of us linguists and etymologists might find it. Be a hipster, use & co-create the Urban Dictionary, and Segway into the new lingo. There certainly is something very classy and non-irrelevant about using the original Italian pronunciation se'gwe; such a proseguimento used appropriately by a gentleman arriving at my door with CHILLED Argyle Champagne on one arm and any variety of lilies on the other will receive my affection, especially if his attire includes an eldredge knot, and he offers a ballet or opera where one might truly enjoy the nuances of proseguire. So that we don't fight it too hard and go mad, but appreciate the rapid and rabid segwaying of our common language, I offer this verifiable quantitative data, a woven tapestry of musical pun, *Soundgarden — by Crooked Steps*, compliments of famed composer Dave Grohl:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTaVHM6HGuQ&feature=youtu.be