# Is "injur" a word?

Tags: meaning, verbs, transitive-verbs, is-it-a-word

Am I going crazy? I think "injur" must be a transitive verb meaning "to cause injury to," as in "the flying debris might injur the bystanders."

Yet when I google around and check [online dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/injur), I get results saying in effect, "did you mean 'injury', or 'incur', etc.?" Also, the spell checker on WordPerfect X5 doesn't recognize the word "injur."

Am I losing it?

Comment: Don't worry, this sort of problem is bound to happen once in a while. If it persists, see your doctor. :)

Comment: The word 'injur' does not appear in my OED.

Comment: which is to say...it's not a word, or rather, it is a misspelling. See [What words are commonly mispronounced by literate people who read them before they heard them?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-words-are-commonly-mispronounced-by-literate-people-who-read-them-before-the). Spellling works the same way sometimes.

Comment: @Mitch - I did not find "injur" in that list.

Answer (score 13):

***[injure](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/injure)***: to do or cause harm of any kind to; damage; hurt; impair.

Comment: Thanks. The nature of my problem is a fruitless search for authority that it's a word. Any suggestions?