# Are there other words with the same weird spelling / pronunciation combo as "victual"?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, list-request

I've always thought that "victual" was a funny word because its spelling and pronunciation are so alien to anything else I know of in the English language.  The free dictionary explains the origin of the spelling and pronunciation [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/victual):

> **Usage Note:** The modern pronunciation of victual, (vtl), represents an Anglicized pronunciation of the Old French form vitaille, which was borrowed into English in the early 14th century. The modern English spelling reflects the fact that in both French and English the word was sometimes spelled with a c, and later also with a u, under the influence of its Late Latin ancestor victulia, meaning "provisions." The word is now occasionally spelled vittle rather than victual, but in either case the pronunciation is (vtl).

I was curious if there are any other words that have similar "ct", "ctu", or "tu" letter combinations that are pronounced like "tt"?

Comment: @simchona: You just robbed me of the chance to say that *wierd* was another example of *weird* spelling!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You can roll it back and then say it

Comment: @And then we all delete these comments here or the joke won't be funny...  :)

Comment: @Brandon: Do you have any opinions about the little controversies we colleagues are cooking up down here?

Comment: Actually, I was only peeved because I'd tried to correct it myself, but the system wouldn't let me because @simchona was already busy making what turned out to be the same edit. I've never experienced that kind of 'lockout' before.

Comment: @Fumble: Ditto, actually.

Comment: @Fumble: It happens all the time on SO.

Comment: @FumbleFingers @simchona Lol, I'm surprised I didn't notice my own typo.  I'm usually pretty good at spotting _mispelled_ words, but apparently I didn't check the title of this question very thoroughly.  I'm glad you got to fight over the chance to correct it for me. =)

Comment: I can't find my copy of Trollope's The Way We Live Now, but I remember I thought it weird that Anthony had one character "say" "vittles" and another "say" "victuals." If you want to check out this assertion, and if you are buying literature by the page, I also remember that by this measure Trollope's book was a real bargain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you think of **indict**?  That is pronounced "in-DITE".

There's a good "bt" one: **subtle**, pronounced "SUT-tl".  The only other "bt" words in which the "bt" is pronounced "t" are: **debt** and **doubt**.

Comment: If we are allowing "bt" then what about "debt"?

Comment: That fits, but its not as counter-intuitive; you can't really say "debbt".  I only included "subtle" because it is so counter-intuitive.

Comment: Of course you *could* say "deBt". It's not unpronounceable, just not what we say. The fact that we enunciate another vowel in "deBIt" is again just because that's what we say.

Comment: @Bogdan: True.  I should probably drop the "bt" thing.

Comment: Looking at the etymology of the word *[interdict](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=interdict),* it should be pronounced *-dite,* just like *indict.* But the dictionaries I've checked don't even give that as an alternate pronunciation.

Answer (score 4):

"Indict" is pronounced "in-dite". Oddly enough, it used to be spelled without a "c" (endite, endight, endyte, indite, ...), as in Old French *enditer*. The "c" was inserted to make it more like Latin (*indictare*), just like in your *victual* example.

Words from drm65's answer follow the same pattern.

- "subtle" was "sutel" (Old French *soutil*) but the Latin is *subtilis* and so we put the "b" back that the French had dropped.
- "debt" was "det", from Old French *dete*, and the Latin is *debitum*
- "doubt" was "dout", from Old French *doter*, and the Latin is *dubium*

Comment: I am now struggling to think of a third example...

Comment: Third example: ctenoid :)

Answer (score 3):

With *ct* at the start of the word, the *c* is silent in the **ctenoid**.

Comment: Ctene, ctenidium, ctenizidae, ctenocephalides, ctenoid, ctenophora, ctenophore, ctenostomata, and ctesiphon.  There!

Comment: That's a great word! If only I had more occasion to use it in a sentence.

Comment: Just make sure not to say ctenoid when you mean cycloid :) Also: **ctenii** -- the tiny teeth on the end of ctenoid scales.

Comment: The complete list is *ctene, ctenidial, ctenidium, ctenobranch,
ctenobranchia, ctenobranchiate, ctenocyst, ctenodont, ctenoid, ctenoidean,
Ctenophora, ctenophoral, ctenophoran, ctenophore,* and *ctenophoric.*

Answer (score 3):

"Blackguard" is pronounced like "blaggard," with the latter even being an alternative spelling, similar to "victual"'s alternative spelling, "vittle."

Answer (score 0):

Only marginally related: there's a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Featherstonehaugh) article about *English names with counterintuitive pronunciations*

It links from *Featherstonehaugh* (='fanshaw'), one of the most well-known (if uncommon) surnames.