# Mischievous pronounced [mis-CHEEV-ee-us] (mischievious)

Tags: pronunciation

I've heard some people pronounce "mischievous" as "mischievious" [mis-CHEEV-ee-us] with an I between the V and the O. The word has three syllables: [MIS-chiv-us]. Why do some people pronounce this word with the four-syllable pronunciation given above? I say it how it's given.

For example, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mischievous) lists the mentioned four-syllable pronunciation as **nonstandard,** meaning it's technically incorrect, but the dictionary added it because of its popular usage.

Comment: They do it to a-NOY-aa-ee you.

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like a rant disguised as a question.

Comment: Some people pronounce the word with the emphasis on the second syllable -- mis-CHEEV-yus.  It is fairly easy for the "yus" to then get stretched into "ee-us".  It's a spoken language, not a computer program.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it *is* about a peeve.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Glad you agree. I had to rephrase my comment three times before posting lest I be labelled impolite to new users. I voted the first close-vote.

Comment: The short answer is that they learned it that way, and because others also use it that way. Hence *February, height, jewelry, sherbet, drown, nuclear, ask, athlete, tenet, cavalry, library, espresso, realtor, cache, foliage*, and [plenty of others](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431). My pet peeves are *culinary* (we don't *cull* the chicken, we cook it) and *Silicon Valley* (the *silicone* is mostly in the other end of California), but I recognize them as that.

Comment: That's funny, @choster.  :-)

Comment: Why would I say it's a computer program, @HotLicks?

Comment: Give me an example about why this isn't about English language and usage because I think this is the opposite, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although *mischievious* isn't listed as a variant spelling in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary*, you could make the case that it is one and that people who say "mis-CHEEV-ee-us" are pronouncing that variation of the word correctly, rather than pronouncing *mischievous* incorrectly. Here is an Ngram chart tracking occurrences of *mischievious* in the Google Books database across the years 1600–2000:

[image]

The two earliest instances of the spelling *mischievious* that a Google Books search finds are from the 1660s. From Thomas Wilson & John Bagwell, [*A Complete Christian Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UVFEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA397&dq=%22mischievious%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=I19OVZKaBMu5sAXa5YGgCQ&ved=0CEsQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22mischievious%22&f=false) (1661):

> **Malicious** ] 2 Joh. 10. Naughty, **mischievious**, evill, wicked.

Nevertheless, that same dictionary also has this entry:

> **Mischievous** ] One devising evill, Prov. 24. 8.

From Richard Head, [*The English Rogue: Described, in the Life of Meriton Latroon*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mGMXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22mischievious%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9ltOVdTgMsTZtQXSk4HwAg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22mischievious%22&f=false) (1665):

> The next day I went into *Lincolns-Inn-fields*, where I saw a company of Rogues, cheats, Pick-pockets, &c, playing at Pidgeon holes (a game much practised there, and in More-fields, by such **mischievious** and lazie Rascals) ...

For the period 1702-1720, Google Books finds twelve unique matches for *mischievious*—enough to suggest that the spelling may have reflected a then-current variant pronunciation, and not merely a series of typographical errors. On the other hand, it is undeniable that a person who fully intends to type *mischievous* may type *mischievious* by mistake.

Comment: I wonder whether the word _devious_ has played a role in the persistence and (minor) popularity of _mischievious_ over the years. Is there any way to investigate such a question?

Comment: Frequency of near occurrence?