# How to pronounce epitome?

Tags: pronunciation

I have always been pronouncing it as *ye-pi-to-m*.

*Usage*

> Kala was considered the epitome(*ye-pi-to-m*) of success by her gym trainer after she lost 30 kgs in just 3 months.

Is it not the case? Does the pronunciation differ across geographies(USA, Britain etc...)?

Comment: uh-PIH-tuh-mee. It's Greek, if that explains anything (compare the pronunciation of *Aphrodite*).

Comment: Related: [What words are commonly mispronounced by literate people who read them before they heard them?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1685/44619)

Comment: @Anonym So we pronounce it like *Hermaphrodite* then? ;-)

Comment: Epi to me. And to you, yippy tummy.

Comment: @Araucaria Haha, that depends. Are we talking about people with both male and female reproductive organs or about the son of Hermes and Aphrodite?

Comment: @Anonym: the second would be [Hermaphroditus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermaphroditus).

Answer (score 1):

Said it wrong, famously, in a 9th grade history presentation and embarrassingly learned the correct way:

1st syllable: short "**e**" (like in ten)... though many native speakers just slur it to "uh"... and millions of English language users from Latin derived language speaking countries will pronounce it like long "a" (as well as more long "o" on the 3rd syllable).

2nd syllable: **pit** (as in, "don't fall in that pit")

3rd syllable: **uh** (as in, "uhhh, Jack? I don't think you're saying that right.")... long "o" is okay to, but rarely fully pronounced in the saying.

4th syllable: **me** (as in "Who has a red face and wants to run away? Me, please.")

Answer (score 0):

I've just looked up the word in on-line dictionary. Here's the word with the transcription

epitome [ɪˈpɪtəmɪ]